# How to create a custom UI?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I was watching this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WX7P6Ru8Lv0) on making a custom UI tab using Python, and in the line `from bpy.types import Menu, Panel, UIList`, I see the names of objects that look like they can all be used to make different UI elements. Does `bpy.types` contain all the objects that people use when they want to make custom UI elements?

Comment: A type is a class that can be used as a template for additional classes by way of inheritance, e.g. `class MyPanel(bpy.types.Panel):`  https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.html .  My suggestion is look thru the "Text Editor > templates > python > Ui *" examples that come with blender.

Answer (score 176, accepted):

Designing an UI or Add-on is basically a combination of supplying *Properties* and the inheritance of built-in *Type classes* ([Panel](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html), [Operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html), [Menu](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html) etc.).

---

### Properties

Start by defining your *Properties* first. Properties are basically 'data types', they can be displayed in the UI for basic user interaction and are accessible from almost anywhere. To populate a complete list use python's `dir()` method on [`bpy.props`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html):

[image]

#### Appearance

- Define a [`BoolProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.BoolProperty) for a 'Checkbox'
- Define a [`FloatProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatProperty) or [`IntProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntProperty) to get a 'Slider'
- Define a [`StringProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.StringProperty) for all different kinds of 'Character Input' or ['File Paths'](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/26906/3710)
- Define an [`EnumProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.EnumProperty) to get a 'Dropdown Menu' or 'Radio Selection'
- Define a [`FloatVectorProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty) or [`IntVectorProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.IntVectorProperty) for *compound values* eg. 'Color Pickers', 'Location Coordinates', 'Velocity Vectors', 'Matrices' etc. 
  ...

#### Property Definition

```
from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       )

my_bool: BoolProperty(
    name="Enable or Disable",
    description="Bool property",
    default = False
    )

my_int: IntProperty(
    name = "Set a value",
    description="Integer property",
    default = 23,
    min = 10,
    max = 100
    )
...
```

Note that as of *Blender 2.8x*, *properties* should be assigned to variables using a single colon `:` instead of the usual assignment operator `=` like in *Blender 2.7x* or older versions of Blender.

---

### Types

The contents of [`bpy.types`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.html) are class templates built for inheritance.

#### Panel

[Panels](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html) are everywhere in Blender so it's the most basic element of the user interface. Where the panel is going to be used is defined by [`bl_space_type`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_space_type#bpy.types.Panel.bl_space_type). Blenders interface is 'context sensitive' so you can define [`bl_context`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html#bpy.types.Panel.bl_context) to get the Panel in one respective Mode *(Object Mode, Edit Mode etc.)*. Further reading: [How can I add a checkbox in the tools UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/35011)

[image]

```
class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello_world"
    bl_label = "Hello World"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        self.layout.label(text="Hello World")

bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
```

**Sub Panels**

[image]

As of Blender 2.8x we can have [sub panels](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/UI_API#Sub_Panels) by assigning a certain panel (parent) to [`bl_parent_id`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=bl_parent_id#bpy.types.Panel.bl_parent_id):

```
import bpy

class HelloWorldPanel:
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_options = {"DEFAULT_CLOSED"}


class HELLO_PT_World1(HelloWorldPanel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "HELLO_PT_World1"
    bl_label = "Panel 1"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="This is the main panel.")


class HELLO_PT_World2(HelloWorldPanel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "HELLO_PT_World1"
    bl_label = "Panel 2"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="First Sub Panel of Panel 1.")


class HELLO_PT_World3(HelloWorldPanel, bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_parent_id = "HELLO_PT_World1"
    bl_label = "Panel 3"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Second Sub Panel of Panel 1.")


classes = (
    HELLO_PT_World1,
    HELLO_PT_World2, 
    HELLO_PT_World3
)

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

See also: *Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Panel*.

#### Operator

The [Operator](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Operator.html) is the most important bit to understand. You can display 'operators' as *Buttons* and once registered and you can call it from everywhere via `bpy.ops.IDNAME()`. That's also the way blender is designed, all *real Buttons* are 'operators' under the hood, mostly written in C but then exposed to python. See also: *Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator...*.

[image]

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_HelloWorld(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "Minimal Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        # Report "Hello World" to the Console
        self.report({'INFO'}, "Hello World")
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_HelloWorld)

# test call the operator
bpy.ops.wm.hello_world()
```

The *Operator class template* comes with [predefined methods](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/19416/what-do-operator-methods-do-poll-invoke-execute-draw-modal), in fact `poll`, `invoke`, `execute`, `draw`, `modal`, and `cancel` which can be used along custom properties for all different kinds of operations and also to provide user interaction, see: [Is there an addon for renaming an object with a keyboard shortcut?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60682) for a complete example of an operator.

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_HelloWorld(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "Minimal Operator"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER'}

    # Operator user properties, should be assigned using a single colon :
    # instead of using an equal sign = in Blender 2.8
    report_flag: bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name = "Report",
        default = True)

    @classmethod # Will never run when poll returns false
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.object

    def invoke(self, context, event): # Used for user interaction
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def draw(self, context): # Draw options (typically displayed in the tool-bar)
        row = self.layout
        row.prop(self, "report_flag", text="Report Hello World")

    def execute(self, context): # Runs by default 
        if self.report_flag:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Hello World")
        else:
            print ("Hello World")
        return {'FINISHED'}

bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_HelloWorld)

# For interaction, pass 'INVOKE_DEFAULT' when calling 
# the operator, this way invoke runs before execute method 
bpy.ops.wm.hello_world('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

Further reading: [How to call a confirmation dialog box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73548/3710) (for *tremendously dangerous operators*).

#### Menu

For a custom menu define/inherit a [Menu Class](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Menu.html#module-bpy.types). Add your operators and properties to the `draw()` function properly *(see also: Text Editor > Templates > Python > UI Menu templates)*.

[image]

```
import bpy

class MyCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Simple Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "MY_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("wm.open_mainfile")
        layout.operator("wm.save_as_mainfile") 

bpy.utils.register_class(MyCustomMenu)

# The menu can also be called from scripts
bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=MyCustomMenu.bl_idname)
```

You can also draw a button to call the menu without declaring any extra operator by `layout.operator("wm.call_menu").name="bl_idname"`

**Submenu**

To get a submenu, call the second one within the parent menu via [`layout.menu(bl_idname)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout.menu#bpy.types.UILayout.menu).

[image]

```
class MyCustomMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "First Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Hello First Menu!", icon='WORLD_DATA')
        
         # call the second custom menu
        layout.menu("OBJECT_MT_sub_menu", icon="COLLAPSEMENU")
        
class MyCustomSubMenu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Sub Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_sub_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Hello Second Menu!", icon='WORLD_DATA')
        
        # call another predefined menu
        layout.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Unwrap").name = "VIEW3D_MT_uv_map" 


# draw a button within the panel to call the first menu
class OBJECT_PT_my_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    ...
    def draw(self, context):
        layout.operator("wm.call_menu", text="Call My Menu").name = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"
        ...
```

---

### Add-on Template

When creating an Add-on, usually a lot of properties are requiered. For a better organisation you can create a 'settings class' by using a [PropertyGroup](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PropertyGroup.html).

```
class MySettings(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty()
    my_int: IntProperty()
    my_float: FloatProperty()
    ...
```

Note that as of Blender 2.8x, module/class registration [has changed](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons#Module_Registration) to prevent name conflicts. `bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)` isn't available anymore so you basically have to register/unregister each class separately or within a loop (best practice). In addition to the [old naming conventions](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_master/info_best_practice.html#style-conventions) you also have to [add a seperator](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons#Naming) like `_OT_`, `_MT_` or `_PT_` to the name of your class based on the inherited class type (`Operator`, `Menu`, `Panel`).

```
classes = (
    WM_OT_HelloWorld,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel,
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
```

The following add-on adds a custom panel to the *Tool Shelf* of the *3D View* and prints the current 'user values' of all custom properties to the console:

[image]

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####


bl_info = {
    "name": "Add-on Template",
    "description": "A demo that adds a custom panel to the 'Tool Shelf' of the '3d View'",
    "author": "p2or",
    "version": (0, 4),
    "blender": (3, 0, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Tools",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "doc_url": "https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332",
    "tracker_url": "https://gist.github.com/p2or/2947b1aa89141caae182526a8fc2bc5a",
    "support": "COMMUNITY",
    "category": "Development"
}


import bpy

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Menu,
                       Operator,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Scene Properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MY_PG_SceneProperties(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(
        name="Bool",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False
        )

    my_int: IntProperty(
        name = "Int",
        description="Integer property",
        default = 23,
        min = 10,
        max = 100
        )

    my_float: FloatProperty(
        name = "Float",
        description = "Float Property",
        default = 23.7,
        min = 0.01,
        max = 30.0
        )

    my_float_vector: FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "Float Vector",
        description="Float Vector Property",
        default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
        #subtype='COLOR',
        min= 0.0, # float
        max = 0.1
    ) 

    my_string: StringProperty(
        name="String",
        description="String Property",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        )

    my_path: StringProperty(
        name = "Directory",
        description="Choose a Directory:",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        subtype='DIR_PATH' # FILE_PATH
        )
        
    my_enum: EnumProperty(
        name="Enum",
        description="Enum Property",
        items=[ ('OP1', "Option 1", ""),
                ('OP2', "Option 2", ""),
              ]
        )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Operators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class WM_OT_HelloWorld(Operator):
    bl_label = "Print Values to the Console"
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world" 
    # WindowManager namespace (wm.hello...) serves as example,
    # You could also use a custom one like: my_category.hello_world
    
    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        # print the values to the console
        print("Hello World")
        print("bool state:", mytool.my_bool)
        print("int value:", mytool.my_int)
        print("float value:", mytool.my_float)
        print("string value:", mytool.my_string)
        print("enum selection:", mytool.my_enum)

        return {'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Menus
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_MT_CustomMenu(Menu):
    bl_label = "Select"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # Built-in operators
        layout.operator("object.select_all", text="Select/Deselect All").action = 'TOGGLE'
        layout.operator("object.select_all", text="Inverse").action = 'INVERT'
        layout.operator("object.select_random", text="Random")
        

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False  # No animation.

        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_enum", expand=True)
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_int")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_float")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_float_vector")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_string")
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_path")
        
        layout.separator(factor=1.5)
        layout.menu(OBJECT_MT_CustomMenu.bl_idname, text="Presets", icon="SCENE")
        layout.operator("wm.hello_world")
        layout.separator()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    WM_OT_HelloWorld,
    MY_PG_SceneProperties,
    OBJECT_MT_CustomMenu,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MY_PG_SceneProperties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Note**: There is also a [gist of this template](https://gist.github.com/p2or/2947b1aa89141caae182526a8fc2bc5a) that can easily be forked. For the Blender 2.7+ or 2.8+ versions of the template, please have look into to the [revisions of this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/posts/57332/revisions).

---

#### More complex examples

- [What ui would work for choosing from a long, long list?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8699/what-ui-would-work-for-choosing-from-a-long-long-list)
- [Create an interface which is similar to the material list box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30444/create-an-interface-which-is-similar-to-the-material-list-box)
- [How to get one UIList to control the contents of another UIList?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/158440/3710)
- [script custom previews in a menu](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/47504/script-custom-previews-in-a-menu)
- ...

Comment: Goodness, this was really thorough! There's way more to Python UI than just bpy.types then haha. Thanks!

Comment: This is an amazingly concise and clear overview that would be great as part of the docs.  It took me weeks to figure this out over many, many examples.

Comment: A lot better than official document. You saved my day!

Comment: I wanted to start messing around with Blender UI, to get familiar in preparation for developing some basic music sequencing/sequencing for Blender (I just love Blender's UI style and highly-consistent hotkey style).  A really minimal LMMS-like addon.  After reading this mammoth of an answer, I think I'm ready to go straight to prototyping!  Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

### Modified version -- for blender 2.80

```
# https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57306/3710
# https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79779/3710

#
# modified for blender 2.80 
# last modification: 2019-09-12 -- add custom-preferences panel -- Emanuel Rumpf --

bl_info = {
    "name": "Add-on Template",
    "description": "",
    "author": "",
    "version": (0, 0, 2),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Tools",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Development"
}

"""
This is an addon - template for blender 2.80 
Use it as base for new addons.
--
Some changes made for blender 2.80 version (from 2.79):
- Properties are annotations now, assigned with : not =
- bl_region_type now is "UI" not "TOOLS"
- Registration procedure changed: 
  Use bpy.utils.register_class() not register_module()

More information see: python api blender 2.80
"""

import bpy

#import collections
#import importlib

#import mathutils
#import math


from bpy.utils import ( register_class, unregister_class )
from bpy.props import ( StringProperty,
                        BoolProperty,
                        IntProperty,
                        FloatProperty,
                        FloatVectorProperty,
                        EnumProperty,
                        PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import ( Panel,
                        AddonPreferences,
                        Operator,
                        PropertyGroup,
                      )



# this must match the addon name, use '__package__'
# when defining this in a submodule of a python package.
addon_name = __name__      # when single file 
#addon_name = __package__   # when file in package 


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   settings in addon-preferences panel 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------


# panel update function for PREFS_PT_MyPrefs panel 
def _update_panel_fnc (self, context):
    #
    # load addon custom-preferences 
    print( addon_name, ': update pref.panel function called' )
    #
    main_panel =  OBJECT_PT_my_panel
    #
    main_panel .bl_category = context .preferences.addons[addon_name] .preferences.tab_label
    # re-register for update 
    unregister_class( main_panel )
    register_class( main_panel )


class PREFS_PT_MyPrefs( AddonPreferences ):
    ''' Custom Addon Preferences Panel - in addon activation panel -
    menu / edit / preferences / add-ons  
    '''
    
    bl_idname = addon_name
    
    tab_label: StringProperty(
            name="Tab Label",
            description="Choose a label-name for the panel tab",
            default="New Addon",
            update=_update_panel_fnc
    )

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()
        col = row.column()
        col.label(text="Tab Label:")
        col.prop(self, "tab_label", text="")





# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   properties visible in the addon-panel 
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class PG_MyProperties (PropertyGroup):

    my_bool : BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False
        )

    my_int : IntProperty(
        name = "Int Value",
        description="A integer property",
        default = 23,
        min = 10,
        max = 100
        )

    my_float : FloatProperty(
        name = "Float Value",
        description = "A float property",
        default = 23.7,
        min = 0.01,
        max = 30.0
        )
    
    my_float_vector : FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "Float Vector Value",
        description="Something",
        default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
        min= 0.0, # float
        max = 0.1
    ) 

    my_string : StringProperty(
        name="User Input",
        description=":",
        default="",
        maxlen=1024,
        )

    my_enum : EnumProperty(
        name="Dropdown:",
        description="Apply Data to attribute.",
        items=[ ('OP1', "Option 1", ""),
                ('OP2', "Option 2", ""),
                ('OP3', "Option 3", ""),
               ]
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   operators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OT_HelloWorldOperator (bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.hello_world"
    bl_label = "Print Values Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        # print the values to the console
        print("Hello World")
        print("bool state:", mytool.my_bool)
        print("int value:", mytool.my_int)
        print("float value:", mytool.my_float)
        print("string value:", mytool.my_string)
        print("enum state:", mytool.my_enum)

        return {'FINISHED'}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   menus
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MT_BasicMenu (bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_select_test"
    bl_label = "Select"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        # built-in example operators
        layout.operator("object.select_all", text="Select/Deselect All").action = 'TOGGLE'
        layout.operator("object.select_all", text="Inverse").action = 'INVERT'
        layout.operator("object.select_random", text="Random")


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#   addon - panel -- visible in objectmode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_my_panel (Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tool"  # note: replaced by preferences-setting in register function 
    bl_context = "objectmode"   

    
#   def __init(self):
#       super( self, Panel ).__init__()
#       bl_category = bpy.context.preferences.addons[__name__].preferences.category 
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        layout.prop( mytool, "my_bool")
        layout.prop( mytool, "my_enum", text="") 
        layout.prop( mytool, "my_int")
        layout.prop( mytool, "my_float")
        layout.prop( mytool, "my_float_vector", text="")
        layout.prop( mytool, "my_string")
        layout.operator( "wm.hello_world")
        layout.menu( "OBJECT_MT_select_test", text="Presets", icon="SCENE")





# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# register and unregister
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    PG_MyProperties,
    #
    OT_HelloWorldOperator,
    MT_BasicMenu,
    OBJECT_PT_my_panel, 
    #
    PREFS_PT_MyPrefs, 
)

def register():
    #
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)
    #
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=PG_MyProperties)
    
    #

def unregister():
    #
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    #
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool  # remove PG_MyProperties 




if __name__ == "__main__":
    pass
    #register()
```

Some changes made for blender 2.80 version:

- Properties are annotations now, assigned with `:` not `=`
- `bl_region_type` now is "UI" not "TOOLS"
- Registration procedure changed:
- Use `bpy.utils.register_class()` not `register_module()`

More information: [python api blender 2.80](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API)

Comment: OMG. Thank you so much. I am learning python in blender. I code a lot in VB.net & C#. Was struggling with the UI stuff. This explained it very well and

Comment: hi, i would like to know what `scene.my_tool` was refering to? because I didnt see where it was first defined?

Comment: oh now i get it, so i hv to register a pointer property to store say some other properties?

Comment: Late to the party. Check the quickUI add on. The version on gumroad is free [1].
[1] https://gumroad.com/l/quickUI

Comment: good synthesis, it would be perfect to add some updates on properties in property group to see where to put them