# What UI panel property type is this and how can I create my own

Tags: python, scripting, panel

How do I make my own 'list' in my custom panel like this?
[image]

I want to be able to acces to chosen value (string) as well...

Bert

Comment: Doesn't give me any information on where the list is located or set-up... I suppose they are in files that are not supposed to viewed by the average blender user...

Comment: You have a complete example in the templates that can be found in the text editor  : have a look to "ui_previews_dynamic_enum.py". This sample shows this kind of menu filled with the png files of a directory.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is an [Enum Property](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_77_1/bpy.types.EnumProperty.html), essentially an array of options that have an identifying name, a displayed name, and a description (shown in the tooltip).

For example:

```
bpy.types.Scene.MyEnum = EnumProperty(
    items = [('one', 'One!', 'The first number'), 
             ('two', 'Two', 'The second number'),
             ('three', 'Three', 'The third number')],
    default = "one",
    description = "Pick a number",
    name = "Numbers")
```

For the first item, "one" is the identifier, "One!" is the name shown in the interface, and "The first number" is shown in the tooltip.

You would access the chosen option using `scene.MyEnum`, and set it using `scene.MyEnum="two"`.

To display the enum in the interface and allow the user to change it, use `layout.prop(scene, 'MyEnum')`

Note: The [code snippets here](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Py/Scripts/Cookbook/Code_snippets/Interface) are very helpful :)

Comment: Thanks for the extraordinary quick and perfect answer Greg!