# Is there an addon for renaming an object with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: workflow, add-on, shortcut

I want to use a keyboard shortcut to bring up a text field for renaming the active object.

As far as I know, currently no such shortcut exists, and making one will require an addon.
I seem to remember reading about just such an addon before, but now I can't remember where (it was a while ago). If I remember correctly, it had some other features too (batch renaming or something).

Anyway, if this functionality or an addon supplying it already exists, where can I find it?

Comment: Select the object, and hit F2 on your keyboard I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need an addon for renaming objects. You can now use Blender's [built in renaming tool](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/blend/rename.html) by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> on the selected object. You can also push <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the batch rename which could be very handy.

Answer (score 18):

I just found one ;)

With the following Add-on enabled, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>R</kbd> to enter a 'new name' for the *active object* as well as rename its *data block* (optional). In order to speed up the process you can hit <kbd>Return</kbd> followed by <kbd>O</kbd> to confirm, after typing the 'new name':

[image]
*Click to enlarge*

**viewport-rename.py**

```
# ##### BEGIN GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
#
#  This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
#  modify it under the terms of the GNU General Public License
#  as published by the Free Software Foundation; either version 2
#  of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
#
#  This program is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
#  but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
#  MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
#  GNU General Public License for more details.
#
#  You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
#  along with this program; if not, write to the Free Software Foundation,
#  Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA 02110-1301, USA.
#
# ##### END GPL LICENSE BLOCK #####
# <pep8 compliant>

import bpy
import re

bl_info = {
    "name": "Viewport Rename",
    "author": "p2or",
    "version": (0, 5),
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Ctrl+R",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "3D View"
}


class ViewportRenameOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Rename selected object(s) in 3D View"""
    bl_idname = "view3d.viewport_rename"
    bl_label = "Viewport Rename"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}
    bl_property = "new_name"

    new_name : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="New Name")
    data_flag : bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Rename Data-Block", default=False)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return bool(context.selected_objects)

    def execute(self, context):
        user_input = self.new_name
        reverse = False
        if user_input.endswith("#r"):
            reverse = True
            user_input = user_input[:-1]

        suff = re.findall("#+$", user_input)
        if user_input and suff:
            number = ('%0'+str(len(suff[0]))+'d', len(suff[0]))
            real_name = re.sub("#", '', user_input)           

            objs = context.selected_objects[::-1] if reverse else context.selected_objects
            names_before = [n.name for n in objs]
            for c, o in enumerate(objs, start=1):
                o.name = (real_name + (number[0] % c))
                if self.data_flag and o.data is not None:
                    o.data.name = (real_name + (number[0] % c))
            self.report({'INFO'}, "Renamed {}".format(", ".join(names_before)))
            return {'FINISHED'}

        elif user_input:
            old_name = context.active_object.name
            context.active_object.name = user_input
            if self.data_flag and context.active_object.data is not None:
                context.active_object.data.name = user_input
            self.report({'INFO'}, "{} renamed to {}".format(old_name, user_input))
            return {'FINISHED'}

        else:
            self.report({'INFO'}, "No input, operation cancelled")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        dpi = context.preferences.system.pixel_size
        ui_size = context.preferences.system.ui_scale
        dialog_size = 450 * dpi * ui_size
        if context.active_object:
            self.new_name = context.active_object.name
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self, width=dialog_size)

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout
        row.row()
        row.prop(self, "new_name")
        row.prop(self, "data_flag")
        row.row()


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    register, unregister and hotkey
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class

    addon_keymaps.clear()
    register_class(ViewportRenameOperator)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ViewportRenameOperator.bl_idname, type='R', value='PRESS', ctrl=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    unregister_class(ViewportRenameOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The Add-on also allows to *batch rename* all objects in the current selection. The suffix is determined by the given number of hash characters at the end of the string. You can simply type `Cube-###` to get *'Cube-001'*, *'Cube-002'* and *'Cube-003'* as well as `Cube-###r` to get a reversed list:

[image]

Repository: https://github.com/p2or/blender-viewport-rename

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! Great find ;)

I wonder if there's a way to get the text field to have focus by default..?

Comment: Nice add-on, and a great way to demonstrate the use of draw, invoke, execute, etc. in a simple operator!

Answer (score 2):

I made a [quick rename addon](https://github.com/Pullusb/quick_rename_menu) myself for exactly this purpose. It doesn't have the capacity of batch renaming like "viewport-rename" do.
But it propose renaming options according to current name (if available).

[image: quick rename pop-up with proposition]

Trigger it with *alt-N*, like *ALT*ernative *N*ame (*ctrl-r* is really good but already taken for bone roll in armature edit mode)

Answer (score 1):

This may end up being a bit of an overkill solution to achieve it, but you could use the Name Panel Addon (available in [Free](https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?272086-Addon-Name-Panel-1-6-(Batch-Naming)) and [Commercial](https://cgcookiemarkets.com/all-products/name-panel/) flavors) to rename your active object.

It's a great addon and I strongly recommend it's use, though it may over complicate in this case, because the addon is a lot more complex and is mainly concerned with batch naming and name copying, among other involved functionality.

It does not assign one hot key by default as far as I know, but you can go to the user preferences and manually assign it yourself.

Just browse to the *File > User Preferences > Input > 3D View >3D View Global* and add a new operator `wm.batch_name` with the desired key combination.

It should call out the operator popup with the (potentially overly complex) popup dialog

**Edit**

Not sure if this is what you want, but to set the name automatically to a specific predefined name you can add another operator `wm.context_set_enum` with *Context Attributes* set to `scene.BatchName.customName and *Value* set to whatever name you want, but I could not do it all (set the name and actual renaming) at once with a single key press.
Perhaps with some additional scripting?