# Batch rename objects with number sequence?

Tags: scripting, objects

Is there a way to batch rename objects in a sequence similar to: object1, object2, object3...? Where 'object' would be any custom name?

I found the [batch rename datablocks](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Extensions:2.6/Py/Scripts/Object/Batch_Rename_Datablocks) script and it was really helpful for renaming a group of objects but gives a sequence like: object.001, object.002, object.003

Is there any way to use this script to give the first kind of sequence?

Comment: Does [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60649/is-there-an-addon-for-renaming-an-object-with-a-keyboard-shortcut) help?

Comment: Thanks poor! Looks like either that or the script below works well. Your link gives the option of connecting it with a hotkey which can be really nice too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Blender 2.79**

```
import bpy

for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects, 1):
    bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
    obj.name = "object" + str(i)
```

**Blender 2.8+**

```
import bpy

for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects, 1):
    bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj
    obj.name = "object" + str(i)
```

Just replace "object" with "your name" and run this in the text editor (make sure you have all objects selected that you want renamed).

Comment: This didn't work for me when using Blender 2.8.

changing line 4 to `bpy.context.view_layer.objects.active = obj` helped.

update cheatsheet here => https://blenderartists.org/t/2-80-cheat-sheet-for-updating-add-ons/1148974

Comment: Answer edited with Furkan's comment ... Thanks man :) BTW - How to number like 01, 001 style?

Comment: @vklidu What do you mean? You want to add leading zeroes all the time or you want to add a zero to each subsequent object in a sequence?

Answer (score 10):

Blender users can now do batch rename with (Menu: Edit ‣ Batch Rename and Hotkey:   Ctrl+F2) without any add-ons. (blender +2.80)

[image]

An example:
[image]

Read this blender manual section for more info: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/files/blend/rename.html#batch-rename

Comment: Yes, but there is not a way to add sequential numbering (if it is not hidden under "Regular Expression" :)

Comment: CTRL+F2 does not work since 2.90 apparently

Comment: @phil123
it did and it does for me. even on v3.0. I will add a screenshot just in case so anyone could find the short key if it does not work for them.

Comment: @vklidu updated

Comment: Nice trick :) so ... You have to do it in two steps. First to rename all objects with number ".001" included (this pushs blender's native numbering to renumber other objects sequently). Secondly use Find/Replace beginning and keep only number https://imgur.com/E9MUTNU (alternatively add suffix). Could you extend your edit, because OP was asking how to start name with sequential numbering ... especially point the trick here. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

I'm sure there are dozens of add-ons floating around that do this since they are quite easy to code and thus a good way to learn python, but here's mine:

https://github.com/gregzaal/batch-renamer

[image: batch renamer screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

blender 2.79 addon bulk rename
[image: example]

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import *

import numpy as np

bl_info = {
    "name": "renameBulk",
    "author": "luis alberto rodriguez montilla",
    "version": (0),
    "blender": (2, 72, 2),
    "location": "VIEW_3D > TOOLS > Tools",
    "warning": "first select the objects",
    "description": "bulk rename",
    "wiki_url": ""
                "",
    "category": "Mesh",
}

def initSceneProperties():
    #para crear un string
    bpy.types.Scene.brStr = StringProperty(
        name = "new name")
    return
#blender tiene dos principales funciones, panel que dibuja
#y operador que ejecuta; puede haber mas de un operador
class BulkRenameUIPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "change Names"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "TOOLS"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    

    def draw(self, context):
        
        layout = self.layout
        scn = context.scene
        layout.prop(scn, "brStr")
        #operator de be estar todo en minusculas y llevar un punto
        layout.operator("bulk.rename_all_objects")



class defStrBulkRename(bpy.types.Operator):

    def defineVar_(self, context):

        scn = context.scene
        brStr = scn["brStr"]
        return brStr
#los nombres de funciones deberan ser diferentes de otros noambres en addons
#de lo contrario sobreescribira los valores de las funciones anteriores
class OBJECT_OT_bukRename(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "bulk.rename_all_objects"
    bl_label = "change bulk name"
    def execute(self, context):
        for i, obj in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects, 1):
            bpy.context.scene.objects.active = obj
            #aquie el (self,context) es necesario para valores entre clases
            obj.name = defStrBulkRename.defineVar_(self,context)+ str(i)
    
        return{'FINISHED'}
#dejar por defecto este tipo de registro, es funcional y funciona siempre
#que no se nesecite mas datos; si no se registra no aparecera nada

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)#register others class
    initSceneProperties()


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)#unregister others class

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: So much code, when only one line is needed: `for i,o in enumerate(bpy.context.selected_objects): o.name = "Object" + str(i).zfill(3)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `batch rename`'s `Set Name` to ensure the naming and default numbering is correct
2. Use `batch rename`'s `Strip Characters` to remove punctuations
3. Use `batch rename`'s `Find/Replace` to remove 00s