# How to bulk rename objects within a target collection?

Tags: scripting

I have hundreds of objects within a collection (Blender 2.8) and would like to avoid manually renaming each object via the UI. I'm new to Blender and noticed there is scripting support. Could anyone help me produce a script to rename my objects?

For example, I would like to rename the objects in my "Water" collection. The current names do not follow a well defined pattern (even though the screenshot may make it look that way). When renaming is done, I do not care about retaining any semblance of the current name. My only requirement is adding a custom prefix. I'm envisioning the renaming to result in object names like: Water1, Water2, etc.

[image]

Comment: This might help https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71993/batch-rename-objects-with-number-sequence. Also, googling 'Blender Bulk Rename' seems to give some good results.

Comment: Yes, I read some of the related questions and answers, and although they do give hints to part of my question, the main missing aspect is how to target a specific collection in script. I cannot find a Blender 2.8 specific answer surrounding collections.

Comment: If you can select the objects within the viewort, you can try [this addon](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/60682/3710). Recently [updated for 2.8x](https://github.com/p2or/blender-viewport-rename/releases/tag/0.0.5).

Comment: Otra versión de tipo función, agregándole la opción de prefijo para los objetos de la colección: def renombrar(coleccion_nombre=None, prefijo=None): if coleccion_nombre is None or prefijo is None: print('No definió coleccion existente o prefijo') return else: coleccion_objetos = bpy.data.collections.get(coleccion_nombre) if coleccion_objetos: for i, objeto in enumerate(coleccion_objetos.objects): nombre = prefijo + '_' + '{0:03d}'.format(i) objeto.name = nombre print('Renombrado satisfactorimente...')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Iterate over collection objects.**

This example is a reasonably simple introduction into scripting blender's python API.

```
import bpy

wcol = bpy.data.collections.get("Water")
if wcol:
    for i, o in enumerate(wcol.objects):
        o.name = "Water%d" % i
```

To ensure they keep their previous name order, and to have "Water1" first rather than "Water0"

```
import bpy

wcol = bpy.data.collections.get("Water")
if wcol:
    for i, o in enumerate(sorted(wcol.objects[:], key=lambda o: o.name)):
        o.name = "Water%d" % (i + 1) # to start from 1
```