# How to automatically rename empties created with hook operator

Tags: python

I need to rename each new empties I've made. Can you help me?

```
import bpy, bmesh

#select vertex

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
obj = bpy.context.active_object
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
bpy.ops.mesh.select_mode(type="VERT")
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action = 'DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
for vert in range(len(obj.data.vertices)):
    obj.data.vertices[vert].select = True
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT') 
    bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()
```

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209342/batch-rename-add-on-inverted-sequential-numbering/

Comment: Related  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209232/blender-python-to-hook-vertex-and-empty

Comment: & with modifiers https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/196746/15543  using operator to add empty. Recommend method of former, (adding via `bpy.data.objects.new(...)`) to avoid  performance issues related to blender operators.

Answer (score 2):

**The hook is the object of last modifier.**

When a modifier is added it is going to be the last one on the modifiers stack. Since the operator has added both the modifier and the empty and assigned it to the object property of the modifier, then

```
new_mod = obj.modifiers[-1]
new_mod.object.name = "Foo"
```

The whole process of adding hooks can be achieved without using the operator as demonstrated here, *or any operator had the empties not been added with one*

[How can I animate a vertex translation of a triangular mesh?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/196746/15543)

and the "opposite" *ie* parenting empties to verts so they follow verts

[Blender python to hook vertex and empty](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/209232/blender-python-to-hook-vertex-and-empty)

Have used `foreach_set` to deselect all edges and faces and each vert.  Basically for a 3 vertex object

```
me.vertices.foreach_set("select", [True, False, False])
```

is equivalent to

```
me.vertices[0].select = True
me.vertices[1].select = False
me.vertices[2].select = False
```

Test Script.

```
import bpy

obj = bpy.context.object
me = obj.data
# deselect all faces and edges
me.polygons.foreach_set("select", (False,) * len(me.polygons))
me.edges.foreach_set("select", (False,) * len(me.edges))
n = len(me.vertices)
for i in range(n):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
    me.vertices.foreach_set("select", [i == j for j in range(n)])
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT') 
    bpy.ops.object.hook_add_newob()
    obj.modifiers[-1].object.name = f"Hook_{i}"
    
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this line as last line:

```
bpy.data.objects['Empty'].name = "Hook1"
```

Comment: It just renames the cube, not the plain axes [![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JWXmp.png

Comment: sorry, you are right...i will search for the right solution

Comment: i updated my answer

Comment: @batFINGER: i did indent it - it didn't work. It changed the cubes name, but not the empty name. And i have no idea why. i just tested it.

Comment: Yep my bad,  forgot it was edit mode. Anyway recommend using API method to add and wire up the hooks and remove the need for edit mode altogether. See my last link under OP.   Test for any preexisting objects named "Empty" first if using method above.