# How do I make a pop up dialog that goes away when pressed "ok"?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I made the code below. It does exactly what I want except that the pop up dialog does not go away after pressing "ok" button on the pop up. Basically I want a pop up dialog where the user enters a name for the scene save. I trimmed the code to make it concise here.

Everything seems to work except that after I put a name in the field and press "ok", the dialog still stays there, instead I want it to go away after pressing "ok"

```
class MYOP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    bl_label = "Scene Save"

    name = StringProperty(name="Name", default="") 

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
        savescene(context, self.name)

        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Menu code:

```
class FILE_MT_SceneSave(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "SceneSave"
    bl_idname = "FILE_MT_scenesave"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scn=context.scene
        wm = context.window_manager
        layout.operator("wm.myop",text="Save")
```

I am targeting Blender 2.80.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you press "Ok" you are calling the execute method of the operator, in which you are re-calling your operator. Get rid of `bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')` in the execute method.

Blender 2.8 uses [annotations](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/) for properties.

Blender 2.8 uses strict [naming conventions](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Reference/Release_Notes/2.80/Python_API/Addons) for operator and panel class names. For the operator with id `wm.myop` the class needs to be named `WM_OT_myop`.  Please check the system console for errors.

[image]

Test script.  Added to text menu of text menu for example sake./

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myop(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"
    # annotations in 2.8
    name : bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name", default="")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)

def menu_draw(self, context):
    self.layout.operator("wm.myop")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myop)
    bpy.types.TEXT_MT_text.append(menu_draw)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myop)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.myop('INVOKE_DEFAULT')
```

---

In order to make the operator work as part of a 'floating menu' you have to set the `operator_context` property of the layout beforehand, which basically allows to display the popup:

```
import bpy

class WM_OT_myop(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "wm.myop"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name", default="")

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        wm = context.window_manager
        return wm.invoke_props_dialog(self)


class Custom_MT_Menu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_label = "Custom Menu"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_MT_custom_menu"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator("wm.save_as_mainfile").copy = True

        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_DEFAULT'
        layout.operator("wm.myop")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(Custom_MT_Menu)
    bpy.utils.register_class(WM_OT_myop)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Custom_MT_Menu)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(WM_OT_myop)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

    # The menu can also be called from scripts
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=Custom_MT_Menu.bl_idname)
```

Further reading: [How to call a confirmation dialog box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73548/3710)

Comment: Well it was not there originally (was only part of the invoke functions), but then the pop-up never shows up :(  Btw this operator is invoked by a bpy.types.Menu item (via layout.operator)

Comment: I have edited the post, and added a gif, running in 2.8.

Comment: Thanks your  code works, I get it but my issue is that I need to call this operator from a menu like `layout.operator("wm.myop",text="Save")` and that is my issue. You are able to call the op from the `main` with `bpy.ops` which naturally works and that is why I stuck that `bpy.ops` inside the operator itself. I hope it makes sense. Basically when I call from a menu via `layout.operator` I cant make it to trigger the pop up.

Comment: I updated my initial post w the menu code

Comment: Thanks I will try it. Meanwhile what I did was to make a secondary operator and call the original operator within that one (after rereading your respond), it seems to work, but your solution sounds more elegant.