# Change the "OK" button name in dialog-boxes?

Tags: python, interface, operator

My question is really simple, by default the button of blender dialog boxes is the "OK" string
what if I want to display something else? like "Execute" or "Play"? Something a bit more explanatory than "OK"...

**Related** : [How to call a confirmation dialog box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/how-to-call-a-confirmation-dialog-box)

[image]

example of dialog box (nothing out of the usual)

```
import bpy

class SimplePropConfirmOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Really?"""
    bl_idname = "my_category.custom_confirm_dialog"
    bl_label = "Do you really want to do that?"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'INTERNAL'}

    prop1: bpy.props.BoolProperty()
    prop2: bpy.props.BoolProperty()

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "YES!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        return context.window_manager.invoke_props_dialog(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        row = self.layout
        row.prop(self, "prop1", text="Property A")
        row.prop(self, "prop2", text="Property B")


class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(SimplePropConfirmOperator.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePropConfirmOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePropConfirmOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Please share code for how you built this panel so we can see your approach

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately this isn't something you have any control over. The `window_manager.invoke_props_dialog` function is defined in C [here](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_operators.c#L1542), and ultimately uses the [`wm_block_dialog_create`](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/594f47ecd2d5367ca936cf6fc6ec8168c2b360d0/source/blender/windowmanager/intern/wm_operators.c#L1367) function, which contains this:

```
uiBut *but = uiDefBut(
        col_block, UI_BTYPE_BUT, 0, IFACE_("OK"), 0, -30, 0, UI_UNIT_Y, NULL, 0, 0, 0, 0, "");
```

As you can see from `IFACE_("OK")`, the text "OK" for the confirm button is hard-coded in the C source, so there's no way to override it short of rebuilding Blender from source.