# Call a Dialog Box without 'OK' confirmation button?

Tags: python, interface

I saw that the F2 rename operator use a dialog box drawing without any OK button
is this achievable with python? Perhaps there's something i missed?

[image]

Comment: Added a new example to https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/73548/31447

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The *Rename Active Item* dialog is actually a regular [`Panel`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Panel.html?highlight=panel#bpy.types.Panel) rather than a [confirmation dialog box](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/how-to-call-a-confirmation-dialog-box) which is then called using [`WM.call_panel()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.wm.html?highlight=call_panel#bpy.ops.wm.call_panel), see `startup/bl_ui/space_topbar.py`:

[image]

```
import bpy

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'TOPBAR'  # dummy
    bl_region_type = 'HEADER'
    bl_label = "Rename Active Item"
    bl_ui_units_x = 14

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        
        item = context.object
        if item:
            layout.label(text="Object Name")
            row = layout.row()
            row.activate_init = True
            row.label(icon='OBJECT_DATA')
            row.prop(item, "name", text="")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    
    # Test call
    bpy.ops.wm.call_panel(name="LayoutDemoPanel")
```

---

I'd recommend just use [`invoke_popup()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.WindowManager.html?highlight=confirm#bpy.types.WindowManager.invoke_props_dialog) instead. It does the same thing, easier to maintain and there is no extra panel class needed to display a few properties:

[image]

```
import bpy

class SimplePopUpOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Really?"""
    bl_idname = "my_category.custom_popup_dialog"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'INTERNAL'}

    item: bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=bpy.types.Object)

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return True

    def execute(self, context):
        self.report({'INFO'}, "YES!")
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.item = context.object
        return context.window_manager.invoke_popup(self)

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.label(text="Object Name")
        row = layout.row()
        row.activate_init = True
        row.label(icon='OBJECT_DATA')
        row.prop(self.item, "name", text="")


class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator(SimplePopUpOperator.bl_idname)

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimplePopUpOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePropConfirmOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimplePopUpOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Code is based on: **[How to call a confirmation dialog box?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/73286/how-to-call-a-confirmation-dialog-box)**