# Insert a FloatVectorProperty into a customized interface

Tags: interface, customization

Referring to [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui), I am trying to build a custom interface starting from the final model "All in One". The problem is that I want to add into my interface a FloatVectorProperty. So, I inserted that into my "My Setting" class, into the "OBJECT_PT_my_panel" class and I am trying to print its values.
But when I add this FloatVectorProperty, the other parameters just disappear and the compiler says to me that "ValueError: bpy_struct "MySettings" registration error: my_vector_property could not register"

That's how I defined the vector property inside the MySetting class:

```
my_floatVectorProperty = FloatVectorProperty(
    description="Something",
    default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
    min=(0.0,0.0,0.0),
    max=(100.0,100.0,100.0),
)
```

Is there a way to fix that so I can add a FloatVectorProperty to the panel and print its values?

Comment: According to the [API](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.props.html?highlight=floatvectorproperty#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty), `min` and `max` are floats - [extended example](https://gist.github.com/p2or/a00bdde9f2751940717a404cf977dd01).

Comment: Oh man, you're right. Stupid mistake. It worked. I was convinced that because the default is a vector, so is the minimum and the maximum. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the API, `min` and `max` are floats so the correct definition is:

```
my_floatVectorProperty = FloatVectorProperty(
  description="Something",
  default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
  min=0.0,
  max=100.0
)
```