# Can I create a custom shelf without scripting?

Tags: scripting

Coming from Maya, I find essential to have my own custom shelf with my most used shortcuts. Can I create one in Blender without scripting it with Python? I can script it if needed

EDIT: 
I'm refering to this: http://worldofleveldesign.com/categories/3d-game-modeling/beginner-series/images/11-mayalt-custom-shelf-01.jpg as the thing I'm looking for. In Maya you can press that little nut in the left to create new tabs and you can press Ctrl + Shift + Clic in any of the tools to create a shortcut inside that tab.

Comment: There is no drag'n drop thing, although easy to achieve with basic python knowledge. Can you specify what you'd like to have?

Comment: Are you asking how to modal a shelf in blender?

Comment: I was refering to this: http://worldofleveldesign.com/categories/3d-game-modeling/beginner-series/images/11-mayalt-custom-shelf-01.jpg
 as the thing I'm looking for. In Maya you can press that little nut in the left to create new tabs and you can press Ctrl + Shift + Clic in any of the tools to create a shortcut inside that tab.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way that I know of natively in blender without using python.
That said, basic ui stuff for blender is fairly simple, so long as you just want to chuck existing operators/functions on a panel.
See [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui) for a quick intro.

If you don't want to learn python, you could try this paid addon (it claims to do more than just pie menus, side panels as well):
https://blendermarket.com/products/pie-menu-editor
(disclaimer: I have never used this addon, so I have no idea how well it works)