# How to make multiple float property in python

Tags: python

What is the python code to make multiple float property like in the mapping node?
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Use a [**`FloatVectorProperty`**](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty) and set its *subtype* to `'XYZ'` or `'TRANSLATION'`.

Currently other available *subtypes* of that property are: `'COLOR'`, `'DIRECTION'`, `'VELOCITY'`, `'ACCELERATION'`, `'MATRIX'`, `'EULER'`, `'QUATERNION'`, `'AXISANGLE'`, `'COLOR_GAMMA'`, `'LAYER'`.

[image]

Ripped from: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (FloatVectorProperty,
                       PointerProperty
                       )

from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       PropertyGroup
                       )


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Scene Properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyProperties(PropertyGroup):

    my_float_vector: FloatVectorProperty(
        name = "Float Vector Value",
        description="Something",
        default=(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 
        min= 0.0,
        max = 0.1,
        subtype = 'XYZ'
        # 'COLOR', 'TRANSLATION', 'DIRECTION', 'VELOCITY', 
        # 'ACCELERATION', 'MATRIX', 'EULER', 'QUATERNION', 
        # 'AXISANGLE', 'XYZ', 'COLOR_GAMMA', 'LAYER'
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "object.custom_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        layout.prop(mytool, "my_float_vector", text="")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    MyProperties,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Could argue the node prop highlighted in question is subtype `'TRANSLATION'`  given the length unit displayed.

Comment: True, Added. Thanks @batFINGER

Answer (score 0):

Blender built-in `mathutils`-`Vector`

> ***class* mathutils.Vector**(seq)
>
> This object gives access to Vectors in Blender.
>
> > **Parameters**: *seq (sequence of numbers)* – Components of the vector, must be a sequence of at least two

[mathutils.Vector](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender2.8/mathutils.html#mathutils.Vector)

Most of the Blender code contain this Vector component for value modification.