# Blend file-wide property?

Tags: python

In my add-on, I would like to add a property that is not scene-specific but unique for the entire project file so I can call it from any scene and always get the same value.

In case you need to know, in my situation it would be a PointerProperty that points to a list of properties of different types.

I know how to add a Scene-specific property by adding a line like this in the register function:

```
bpy.types.Scene.my_prop = PointerProperty(type=my_list_of_properties)
```

But what about a Project File property? Is that even a thing?

Comment: You can eg. use addon preferences or the window manager.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry I missed that other question.

Comment: Glad I could help @ChameleonScales

Comment: I'm not clear on the first given tip. The users over there haven't been active recently so I'm unsure I'll get a response from them but I commented there anyway.

Comment: What *exactly* is not clear? Suggest to use `bpy.types.WindowManager`, also done that way in rigify.

Comment: I wrote it in a comment there but I don't know what he means by a dummy ID block and what the python command would look like.

Comment: I think he means creating a text block to store the value there. Why not the WindowManager?

Comment: because with WindowManager, the value gets deleted if you revert the file and the property itself gets deleted if you close and reopen Blender. I would like the property to be stored (per blend file, not globally like Blender's User Preferences).

Comment: Again, not possible. You have to find a way around that e.g. by using a handler per file load: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/150977/31447

Comment: I'll try that, thanks.