# Create a Material using Python script

Tags: python, scripting, node-editor, add-on, shaders

I have Created a Node group Using Python Script and Now I wan't is To Convert This To Add-on,
I Wanted that whenever I click a Button "Add Test Material",

It Create a Material which consist of That Node group

When this Script is Run It Appears in Physics Panel,

Can anyone Help me Out How to do that ?

This is the Script which is similar To My Script - [Python Script(Link to Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B1v4Xs2EZrdJZU5L6QyR85eQqSZ1I1yX?usp=sharing)

My Script is Having following errors -

1. Node Group is Added But it is Not Connected to Material Output, how to connect this to Material Output Node.
2. When I Click Add "Test Material" Button in the Physics Panel(here this script appears) it should add this material to node editor but material is not added
   but if i just re-run the script the material is added

Can Anyone Rectify this Script
I will be Very Glad If My First script becomes Successful as I am Noob to Scripting in Blender.

Comment: More effort please. Also, please post your code. BTW: the answer is simple once you understand what an operator is, read: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)

Comment: I have Edited this Question to make it more Clear Please help me now, I need Help