# API: How to hide faces, edges, vertices of an object in Object Mode?

Tags: python, mesh, object-mode

I am following [this tutorial](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui) for a custom GUI, accessible in the Object Mode, working in Blender 2.8.0.
There, I have a several collections with one object comprised of one mesh each. Currently, I hide a whole object `cubes_0` via a boolean property `show_0_cubes` as follows:

```
bpy.data.collections['cubes_0'].hide_viewport = not mytool.show_0_cubes
```

Now, I want to hide all faces of the mesh/object that have more than a certain distance from the origin. However, calling `face.hide = True` does not have any effect in object, but only in edit mode. There, I don't see my GUI. How do I hide certain faces, edges, vertices in Object Mode?

Answer (score 2):

Create vertex group of vertices/edges/faces you want to hide.
Add Mask modifier, there select vertex group from list and press invert button (<->)

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

To answer your question as far as a know you can't hide faces in object mode,
you would need to separate the faces as a separate object and hide that instead and join it again later.

An alternative would be to try to make your GUI visible in edit mode or maybe use a material to represent *"hidden"*, you may even be able to make it transparent and in certain view modes it would essential be hidden.

I'm sorry I couldn't be more helpful.

-

[bpy.ops.mesh.hide(unselected=False)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.hide)

works copy and pasted, just make sure you have your faces, edges or vertices already selected and you're in editmode.

Edit: might also be useful
[bpy.ops.mesh.reveal(select=True)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.ops.mesh.html#bpy.ops.mesh.reveal)

Comment: ... question does stipulate object mode.

Comment: thank you I missed that, sorry!