# Trying to make a menu using multiple modules

Tags: scripting, add-on

It's not giving any erros when installing it, also tested the operators before and and they were working fin but i can't make the menu show up. I was trying to call it using "DC_MT_macro_menu" in a shortcut.

Mainly use [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158287/how-can-i-create-an-advanced-addon-with-a-gui-and-multiple-settings-for-blender) post as reference, though he is using panel instead of menu.

The init file

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Popup Macro",
    "author": "",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "DC_MT_macro_menu",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "",
}

}

import bpy
from . macro_menu import DC_MT_macro_menu
from . macro_classes import DC_OT_bevel_subdiv, DC_OT_bevel_second
    
classes = (
    DC_MT_macro_menu,
    DC_OT_bevel_subdiv,
    DC_OT_bevel_second,
       
)
register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

The menu "macro_menu"

```
import bpy

class DC_MT_macro_menu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "DC_MT_macro_menu"
    bl_label = "Macro"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("3dview.bevel_subdiv")
        layout.operator("3dview.bevel_second")
```

And the operators "macro_classes"

```
import bpy

class DC_OT_bevel_subdiv(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "3dview.bevel_subdiv"
    bl_label = "Subdivision Workflow"
    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        bm = ob.modifiers.get("Bevel")
            
        bm = ob.modifiers.new(name="Bevel", type='BEVEL')
        bm.segments = 2
        bm.profile = 1
        bm.limit_method = 'WEIGHT'
        bm.miter_outer = 'MITER_ARC'
        bm.use_clamp_overlap = False
                    
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
class DC_OT_bevel_second(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "3dview.bevel_second"
    bl_label = "Second Bevel"
    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        bm = ob.modifiers.get("Bevel")
           
        bm = ob.modifiers.new(name="secBevel", type='BEVEL')
        bm.limit_method = 'ANGLE'
        bm.miter_outer = 'MITER_ARC'
        bm.use_clamp_overlap = False
                     
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Modularise your modules**

IMO rather than importing and cherry picking classes from submodules, instead can import the module and call its register method.

For testing have placed the addon in a  `testing_testing` folder, and given it the "Testing" category... will of-coarse need to rename to something more suitable.

Notice the submodules are imported from `testing_testing` rather than from current folder `.` which requires the addon must have the name specified by folder. This makes the imports viable when run from main thread. (eg tested in text editor).

Can alter the submodules by adding removing other classes without the need to edit init file. Only need to edit again for a new submodule.  *Can use something like `pkgutils.list_modules` to look for modules in root folder and automate the imports of each, hence never needing to touch init to have any module placed in folder registered.*

Reworked code.

*`testing_testing/__init__.py`*

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Popup Macro",
    "author": "",
    "version": (1, 0),
    "blender": (2, 83, 0),
    "location": "DC_MT_macro_menu",
    "description": "",
    "warning": "",
    "doc_url": "",
    "category": "Testing",
}

# can use importlib.reload here instead 
import bpy
from testing_testing import operators, menus

modules = (operators, menus)


def register():
    for m in modules:
        m.register()


def unregister():
    for m in modules:
        m.unregister()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*`testing_testing/operators.py`*

```
import bpy


class DC_OT_bevel_subdiv(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "3dview.bevel_subdiv"
    bl_label = "Subdivision Workflow"

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        bm = ob.modifiers.get("Bevel")

        bm = ob.modifiers.new(name="Bevel", type='BEVEL')
        bm.segments = 2
        bm.profile = 1
        bm.limit_method = 'WEIGHT'
        bm.miter_outer = 'MITER_ARC'
        bm.use_clamp_overlap = False

        return {'FINISHED'}


class DC_OT_bevel_second(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "3dview.bevel_second"
    bl_label = "Second Bevel"

    def execute(self, context):
        ob = context.object
        bm = ob.modifiers.get("Bevel")

        bm = ob.modifiers.new(name="secBevel", type='BEVEL')
        bm.limit_method = 'ANGLE'
        bm.miter_outer = 'MITER_ARC'
        bm.use_clamp_overlap = False

        return {'FINISHED'}


classes = (DC_OT_bevel_second, DC_OT_bevel_subdiv,)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

*`testing_testing/menus.py`*

```
import bpy

class DC_MT_macro_menu(bpy.types.Menu):
    bl_idname = "DC_MT_macro_menu"
    bl_label = "Macro"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        layout.operator("3dview.bevel_subdiv")
        layout.operator("3dview.bevel_second")


classes = (DC_MT_macro_menu,)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
    # test call
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu(name=DC_MT_macro_menu.bl_idname)
```

Note can test if a module has a register method using

```
if hasattr(m, "register"):
    m.register()
```

On linux can select the folder and compress

[image]

A zip file that follows convention recommended here [Addons: Only some .zips will install](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/39745/addons-only-some-zips-will-install)

Note: look for the error if it is saying the folder already exists then choose overwrite option, remove previous installation (delete folder, or hit remove button on addon)

The enabled addon,

[image]

after which the menu can be called from  for instance the python console

[image]

Running menus.py in text editor will also make the menu popup via a test call.

To hang your menu onto another during register, recommend writing your own `register` and `unregister` methods instead of using the factory generated methods.

Finally to make a shortcut to popup your menu, as displayed above the operator is "wm.call_menu" and set its name property to the `bl_idname` of your menu.

Comment: So i copied the changes you made 1 to 1 and changed the folder name to testing_testing, just so i could test here to see if i would get any errors, and i do. When i call the menu via the text editor it works as expected, the menu popsup and work just fine. But when i try to install it the console says that the modules were installed, yet the addon checkbox won't let me "check it", and when calling the menu via the console i get an error. [link](https://prnt.sc/t59cbo). The error happens in both 2.83 and 2.90. You have any idea of what could that be?

Comment: Try now. accidentally dropped an "n" in pasting.  Had `m.uregister` corrected (via one character edit)  to `m.unregister`.  Look for error messages in console, eg `module has no attribute uregister`

Comment: Same problem still, it says addon not found: 'testing_testing' on the system console. I am zipping the testing_testing folder with the 3 script inside it. Is that right or should i have any of the scripts inside another folder?

Comment: See https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/39747/15543   What is important is that there is a folder named "testing_testing" in your addons folder after installing.  Note can revert back to the `from . import` and it won't matter what the name of folder is (as long as it can be a python module name eg no periods, slashes, sloshes etc)   IMO it is much better if we know the addon will have a consistent package name.   If the code above is installed in a folder named `testing_testing` can confirm that enabling and disabling works as expected.

Comment: I am so stupid, i read the init file about 10 times and only realized that i should have changed the 2 other script files names to menus and operators after you made an update to the post. Sorry for the trouble and thank you very much for the help!

Comment: Got there in the end.  The names are by way of suggestion only.  Hope this helps... got to how to make a multi-file addon in the end.. lol.

Comment: this is a Life Saver

Comment: Sorry if this is somehow obvious, but is it possible to load modules from different files in Blender's text editor? I could only make this work by zipping the files, files in sub folder and then installing the zip as addon. It is quite tedious to do this constantly.

Comment: I've followed everything you said but still I get an error `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`. Please help me I spend all my day to resolve this. However, I can't go more further right now. I'm using v2.93.1