# fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!:

Tags: python, scripting, materials

I tried to make a multiple file add-on using _ *init* _.py file I have two files from which I am trying to import operator and panel **first file** is *material_operator.py* in which I have defined an operator
and **second file**  is *panel.py* and in this, I have created a panel for the add-on.
so, totally 3 files-

1. _ *init* _.py
2. material_operator.py
3. panel.py

so when I install the add-on it is successfully installed and works properly, but the problem is when I open **console** it gives the following error -

```
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!:
'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.83\\scripts\\addons\\panels.py' 
fake_module: addon missing 'bl_info' gives bad performance!:
 'C:\\Users\\ADMIN\\AppData\\Roaming\\Blender Foundation\\Blender\\2.83\\scripts\\addons\\shader.py'
```

my script is as follows -

1. **_ *init* _.py**

   ```
   bl_info = {
   "name": "Add Test Material",
   "author": "Rakesh Choudhary",
   "version": (1, 0),
   "blender": (2, 83, 0),
   "location": "View3D > Sidebar > Test Material Node",
   "description": "Click on the 'Test Material' button to add a material to your object.",
   "warning": "",
   "wiki_url": "",
   "category": "3D View"
   }

   import bpy
   from bpy.types import (
       Operator,
       Panel,
   )
   from . import material_operator
   from . import panel



   def register():
       material_operator.register()
       panel.register()

   def unregister():
       material_operator.unregister()
       panel.unregister()

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       register()
   ```
2. **material_operator.py** - in this an operator is created in which a material is made

   ```
   import bpy
   from bpy.types import (
       Operator,
       Panel,
   )


   class TEST_MATERIAL_OT_add_material(Operator):
       bl_idname = "test_material.add_material"
       bl_label = "Add Test Material"
       bl_description = "This button will add a material to your object"

       def execute(self, context):
           self.create_material()
           return {'FINISHED'}

       def create_material(self):
           test_shader_mat = bpy.data.materials.new("TestMat")
           mesh = bpy.context.object.data
           mesh.materials.clear()
           mesh.materials.append(test_shader_mat)
           bpy.context.object.active_material.use_nodes = True

           for mat in bpy.data.materials:
               if "TestMat" in mat.name:
                   nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
                   for node in nodes:
                       if node.type != 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL':  # skip the material output node as we'll need it later
                           nodes.remove(node)

           # Creating Node Group Test_Material
           group = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type="ShaderNodeTree", name="Test_Material")

           # Creating Group Input
           group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Diffuse Color")
           group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Glossy Color")
           group.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Glossyness")
           input_node = group.nodes.new("NodeGroupInput")
           input_node.location = (-800, 0)

           # Creating Group Output Node
           group.outputs.new("NodeSocketShader", "Diffuse Color")
           group.outputs.new("NodeSocketShader", "Glossy Color")
           group.outputs.new("NodeSocketShader", "Mix Output")

           output_node = group.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")
           output_node.location = (1500, 0)

           # Creating Diffuse Node
           diffuse_node = group.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
           diffuse_node.location = (150, 100)

           # Creating Glossy Node
           glossy_node = group.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy')
           glossy_node.location = (300, 250)

           # Creating Mix Shader Node
           mix_shader_node = group.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMixShader')
           mix_shader_node.location = (450, 100)

           #Creating Color Ramp ------------------------------------------------------
           col_ramp = group.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeValToRGB")
           #col_ramp.name = "col_ramp"
           col_ramp.location = (400, -300)
           col_ramp.color_ramp.elements.remove(col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0])

           col_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.750)
           col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].color = (0,0,0,1)


           col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].position = (1.0)
           col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].color = (1, 1, 1, 1)


           # Creating Links Between Nodes----------------------------------------------
           group.links.new(diffuse_node.outputs["BSDF"], mix_shader_node.inputs[1])
           group.links.new(glossy_node.outputs["BSDF"], mix_shader_node.inputs[2])
           group.links.new(input_node.outputs["Diffuse Color"], diffuse_node.inputs[0])
           group.links.new(input_node.outputs["Glossy Color"], glossy_node.inputs[0])
           group.links.new(input_node.outputs["Glossyness"], glossy_node.inputs[1])
           group.links.new(output_node.inputs["Diffuse Color"], diffuse_node.outputs[0])
           group.links.new(output_node.inputs["Glossy Color"], glossy_node.outputs[0])
           group.links.new(output_node.inputs["Mix Output"], mix_shader_node.outputs[0])
           group.links.new(col_ramp.outputs["Color"], mix_shader_node.inputs[0])



           # Putting Node Group to the node editor
           tree = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree
           group_node = tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
           group_node.node_tree = group
           group_node.location = (-40, 300)
           group_node.use_custom_color = True
           group_node.color = (1, 0.341, 0.034)
           group_node.width = 250

           shader_node_output_material_node = tree.nodes["Material Output"]
           links = tree.links
           links.new(group_node.outputs[0], shader_node_output_material_node.inputs[0])

           #Material ends here------------------------------



   classes = (TEST_MATERIAL_OT_add_material)


   def register():
       bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_MATERIAL_OT_add_material)



   def unregister():
       bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_MATERIAL_OT_add_material)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       register()
   ```
3. **panel.py** - this is the file in which panels are created

   ```
   import bpy
   from bpy.types import (
       Operator,
       Panel,
   )


   class TEST_MATERIAL_PT_layout_panel(Panel):
       bl_label = "Test Material Node"
       bl_category = "Test Material"
       bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
       bl_region_type = "UI"

       def draw(self, context):
           layout = self.layout
           layout.operator("test_material.add_material", icon='IMPORT')


   def register():
       bpy.utils.register_class(TEST_MATERIAL_PT_layout_panel)


   def unregister():
       bpy.utils.unregister_class(TEST_MATERIAL_PT_layout_panel)

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       register()
   ```

Can anyone tell me what I am missing here?

Comment: Replace: `mesh = bpy.context.object.data` by **`mesh = context.object.data`**, `bpy.context.object.active_material.use_nodes = True` by **`context.object.active_material.use_nodes = True`** and `bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree` by **`context.object.active_material.node_tree`**...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Multi file addons require their own folder.**

The issue you are having is, `addons` is your addons folder.  The error reports that all of your files are there.  Having an `__init__.py` in your addons folder is a bad idea too. An init in a folder tells python to treat it as a module.   *Fortunately, I believe the devs foresaw this possibility and the folder is not directly import, otherwise you'd snaff up all the addons.*

Instead if your addon is to be called `my_addon` and has another file `foo.py` create the structure like so

```
addons/
    my_addon/
        __init__.py
        foo.py
```

Having erroneously placed all  files in the `addons` folder,it sees `panels.py` as an addon to install, which is missing the `bl_info` dictionary. -> The error.

Related

Recently answered giving  a run down on a multi file addon here [Trying to make a menu using multiple modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817)

Comment: @Rakeshchoudhary  Addon is looking good. A small suggestion.  If using context in an operator method  go for `def create_material(self, context)` and pass context as you would calling other methods like `invoke, execute, and draw` eg with `self.create_material(context)` At the time being this does not alter the result, as AFAIK the context passed and `bpy.context` are always same, even if context is overridden.  If in the future this is changed it could result in context passed in operators with overridden context may not match "actual context",  then it would be a difficult issue to debug.