# How to import a class from other script

Tags: python, scripting, add-on, import, error

Im trying to import the class named "MyOperator", which is in the script "Operator.py", into the script "**init**.py" but the console shows me: **ImportError: cannot import name 'Operator' from '**main**' (_*init*_.py)** Note: Operator.py and **init**.py are in the same location. Im doubting too about register the class this way: `bpy.utils.register_class(Operator.MyOperator)` or this way `Operator.MyOperator.register()`I have read a lot in different posts and i can't fix this problem.. The main script is:

```
import bpy
from . import Operator

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the scene context of the properties editor"""
    bl_label = "Layout Demo"
    bl_idname = "SCENE_PT_layout"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "scene"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        scene = context.scene

        # Create a simple row.
        layout.label(text=" Simple Row:")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(scene, "frame_start")
        row.prop(scene, "frame_end")
        
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator('my.operator',text="Operator", icon='MOD_MESHDEFORM')
        
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(Operator.MyOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(LayoutDemoPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(Operator.MyOperator)

if __name__ == "main":
    register()
```

Operator.py

```
import bpy
class MyOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname= "my.operator"
    bl_label = "Mi Operador"
    
    def execute(self,context):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        return {'FINISHED'}
    
    def register():
        bpy.utils.register_class(MyOperator)
    
    def unregister():
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyOperator)
```

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/183817/15543

Comment: Hello, i've read that post and other similar and I can't fix the problem, the way of that post is avaiable to do it in the text editor? Or only works if I install the Addon? Can you help me, please? Thanks u

Comment: Looks like you are  calling register method from the main thread, _ie_ when `__name__ ==  "__main__"`    Install as an addon and enable it, in which case dot  imports have a  module path.  In the link posted it mentions this.  If your add is in a folder named "foo_bar" can `from foo_bar import Operator`

Comment: Thanks u so much, I was trying to do the import in the Text Editor of Blender. Installing the scripts as an Addon I dont have more problems with the import. Thanks you sou much again, I had a headhache with this.