# How can I access a custom property from different operator?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I'm making an **addon** which contains an **`__init__.py`** **file**, the **`fu3dm_main.py`** **file** where I place my **panel** and the **`fu3dm.py`** **file** where I place all my **operators**. Two operators in this case.

Here is a working example of the `__init__.py` file:

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Test - Addon",
    "author" : "Simonetos The Greek <simonetos.the.greek@gmail.com>",
    "description" : "An addon for tests.",
    "blender" : (2, 90, 1),
    "version" : (1, 0, 0),
    "location" : "View3D",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

import os
import bpy
import bpy.utils.previews
from . fu3dm      import *
from . fu3dm_main import *

classes = (
    fu3dm.ops.FU3DM_OT_Operator_A,
    fu3dm.ops.FU3DM_OT_Operator_B,
    fu3dm_main.FU3DM_OP_Main_Panel
)

register, unregister = bpy.utils.register_classes_factory(classes)
```

The `fu3dm_main.py` file:

```
import bpy
from . fu3dm import *

class fu3dm_main():
    """Main class"""
    class FU3DM_OP_Main_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
        """Main panel class"""
        bl_idname = "fu3dm.main_panel"
        bl_label = "TEST ADDON"
        bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
        bl_region_type = "UI"
        bl_category = "FU3DM"

        def draw(self, context):
            layout = self.layout
            row = layout.row()
            row.operator("fu3dm.operator_a")
            row = layout.row()
            row.operator("fu3dm.operator_b")
```

And the `fu3dm.py` file:

```
import bpy

class fu3dm():
    class ops():
        """All operators"""
        class FU3DM_OT_Operator_A(bpy.types.Operator):
            bl_idname = "fu3dm.operator_a"
            bl_label = "Operator A"
            bl_description = "..."
            bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

            gender : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Gender", description="...", items= [('OP1', "Male", ""), ('OP2', "Female", "")], default='OP1')

            def draw(self, context):
                layout = self.layout
                row = layout.row()
                row.label(text="Gender:")
                row.prop(self, "gender", text="")

            def execute(self, context):
                if self.gender == 'OP1':
                    print('Male')
                elif self.gender == 'OP2':
                    print('Female')
                return {"FINISHED"}

        class FU3DM_OT_Operator_B(bpy.types.Operator):
            bl_idname = "fu3dm.operator_b"
            bl_label = "Operator B"
            bl_description = "..."
            bl_options = {'REGISTER','UNDO'}

            face : bpy.props.EnumProperty(name="Face", description="...", items= [('OP1', "Face #1", ""), ('OP2', "Face #2", "")], default='OP1')

            def draw(self, context):
                layout = self.layout
                row = layout.row()
                row.label(text="Face:")
                row.prop(self, "face", text="")

            def execute(self, context):
                if fu3dm.ops.FU3DM_OT_Operator_A.gender == "OP1":
                    print('Male')
                    # And do something...
                elif fu3dm.ops.FU3DM_OT_Operator_A.gender == "OP2":
                    print('Female')
                    # And do something...
                return {'FINISHED'}
```

What I want to do is to **check** if the "**gender**" **`EnumProperty`** from **`fu3dm.operator_a`** is **`'OP1'`** or **`'OP2'`** and then do some things. But I want to do that **through** **`fu3dm.operator_b`** **`execute`** function.

I tried this `if fu3dm.ops.FU3DM_OT_Operator_A.gender == "OP1":` etc, but I got this **error** `AttributeError: type object 'FU3DM_OT_Operator_A' has no attribute 'gender'`. So **how can I access** this "**gender**" **`EnumProperty`** but from **different operator**?

Comment: Have tried before to recommend against this nesting of classes to make a psuedo namespace of sorts, and also suggested using a register method per  module.  At issue here is you are comparing apples and oranges. `gender` is a property defined via a  class annotation , which when registered becomes  an operator property `bpy.ops.foo.bar(gender="XX")` or `self.gender` in method where self is an instance of the registered operator. It is not a class property.  `fu3dm.ops.FU3DM_OT_Operator_A.gender == "OP1"` will not work on so many levels.   Three or four questions back suggested making

Comment: preferences in addon prefs or a scene group property, where they would be available from context at any time eg `context.preference.addons["foo"]`.

Comment: Yes I know you are against this nesting classes, I haven't forget that. But how will I tidy up my code? This is just 0,1% of my original code!!! I have to separate so many things in groups (classes and subclasses). If I just put one on top of the other, I'll just create a hell of code. As for "using a register method per module", I plan to do as the example you gave me last time. I just haven't do that yet. Anyway, I'll study again your links and I will change everything...

Comment: Would ditch the outer fudm and inner  ops and main  classes and put operators in `ops.py` other in `main.py` ... then if your addon is called fu3dm can `from fu3dm.ops import Foo` in code anywhere in blender. To me, the way it is,  doing little more than   wasting 8 columns of precious  indent.  Consider looking at the way add curve sapling does similar using one "monster" redo panel to generate model based on selections. Or like rigify where you make your selections and then generate based on them instead of "live" via the op.

Comment: I am remaking it all like you said here (https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817)!!!