# Trouble with __init__.py loading addon with multple files

Tags: python, interface, add-on, import

I've written a custom addon for a few Pie menus but can't figure out how to load them together from a __init.py

Currently they are all split into these four files:

`PIE_context.py`, `PIE_mode.py`, `PIE_uvcontext.py`, `PIE_uvmode.py`

They all work when installed on their own, register shortcuts and everything. Despite reading around I can't figure out how to import them together from the `__init__.py` file below.
The shortest of the four `PIE_uvcontext.py`is below that:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Context Pie",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "User Interface",
    "version": (0, 1, 0, 0),
    "location": "UV Editor, View3D, Mesh, Curve",
}

# Blender imports
import bpy

#from bpy.props import *
from . import PIE_context
from . import PIE_mode
from . import PIE_uvcontext
from . import PIE_uvmode

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    
    PIE_context.register()
    PIE_mode.register()
    PIE_uvcontext.register()
    PIE_uvmode.register()

def unregister():

    PIE_context.unregister()
    PIE_mode.unregister()
    PIE_uvcontext.unregister()
    PIE_uvmode.unregister()
 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "UV Pie: 'Shift + Right Mouse'",
    "description": "UV Pie Menu",
    "version": (0, 1, 2),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "UV Editor",
    "category": "Pie Menu"}

import bpy
from bpy.types import (
    Header,
    Menu,
    Panel,
)
from bpy.app.translations import contexts as i18n_contexts

# Reference context menu: IMAGE_MT_uvs_context_menu
class IMAGE_PIE_MT_uvContext(Menu):
    bl_label    = ""

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator_context = 'INVOKE_REGION_WIN'
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        
        # WEST
        pie.operator("uv.pin").clear = False
        # EAST
        pie.operator("uv.pin", text='Unpin').clear = True
        # SOUTH
        pie.operator("uv.minimize_stretch")
        # NORTH
        pie.operator("uv.unwrap")
        # NORTH-WEST
        pie.operator("uv.pack_islands")
        # NORTH-EAST
        pie.operator("uv.average_islands_scale")
        # SOUTH-WEST
        pie.operator("mesh.mark_seam", text='Mark Seam').clear = False
        # SOUTH-EAST
        pie.operator("mesh.mark_seam", text='Clear Seam').clear = True

        # Static face menu
        pie.separator()
        pie.separator()

        dropdown = pie.column()
        gap = dropdown.column()
        gap.separator()
        gap.scale_y = 8

        dropdown_menu = dropdown.box().column()
        dropdown_menu.scale_y=1

        dropdown_menu.operator("uv.stitch")
        dropdown_menu.operator("uv.weld")
        dropdown_menu.operator("uv.remove_doubles")


classes = [
    IMAGE_PIE_MT_uvContext]

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    if wm.keyconfigs.addon:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='UV Editor')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new('wm.call_menu_pie', 'RIGHTMOUSE', 'PRESS', shift=True)
        kmi.properties.name = "IMAGE_PIE_MT_uvContext"
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
            km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Thanks!

Comment: I have the files in the same folder and simply press 'install...' in blender preferences and select the `__init__.py` file.
Perhaps that is just not the way to do it?!?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817   (make a zip file to install multi-file addons)

Comment: Thank you!
That got it working. Did think I had missed something simple. Can't wait to release it (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by @batFINGER in comment:

Just had to zip the folder with files in!
[Trying to make a menu using multiple modules](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817)