# No module named 'particles_to_leaves'

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

i was making a addon to create a stylized tree and when i run the script in the text editor of blender it run well , but when i convert it to a package ZIP to use it like a addon . Console show me No module named 'particles to leaves'

```
bl_info={
    "name":"Become to tree",
    "author":"Cristofer Erik Calvo Milla",
    "version":(1,0),
    "blend":(2,91,0),
    "location":"View3d>Tool",
    "warning":"",
    "wiki_url":"",
    "category":"Add Mesh"
    
}
import bpy
import sys
import os
import importlib
from bpy.props import PointerProperty
from bpy.props import EnumProperty

sys.path.insert(1,'.\Branch')
sys.path.insert(2,'.\Find_Position')
sys.path.insert(3,'.\particles_to_leaves')
sys.path.insert(4,'.\Transform_branch')

from particles_to_leaves import system_particles
from Branch import Type_Trunk
```

[image]

now i can add my addon to blender, but i can't see my menu in view -->UI

[image]

Comment: Would recommend making paths local to addon folder and using  `from . import foo`    .... rather than append relative paths (a single escape character `\` in a string is another issue) Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183773/trying-to-make-a-menu-using-multiple-modules/183817#183817

Comment: thanks friend, it worked, but now my menu does not appear . it shoud be in Viewport3d--> UI  but it doesn't show