# How to get one UIList to control the contents of another UIList?

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I have two dynamic lists. One is for strings and another one for objects. When the string changes I need the other list to show the objects assigned to the string in the first list. So I would need something like a "global 2d array", but the only way I know of in Blender is assigning properties to ex. the scene. But I'm not familiar with ways to deal with stuff like: ["BOB", ("Camera", "Light", "Cube")] using properties. How would you guys solve this? Here'a a gif of the UI:
[image]

The code is far to big to paste here, but is based on p2or's UIList code:  https://www.codepile.net/pile/0J6E3WxB

Comment: Have you looked into https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.props.html#collection-example ?

Comment: your link to paste of code -> The resource could not be found.

Comment: https://www.codepile.net/pile/0J6E3WxB

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*It's indeed tricky getting all the details sorted but it is possible to make it work properly:*

[image]

(Minimal) Example: https://gist.github.com/p2or/4635887cfe6ed9e652eadc8aa7585a87

---

#### Data Structure

I'd suggest create a *nested collection* for your objects as part of the *main collection* (users), register e.g. per scene to get your data structure working and then test using the *Console* in the first place:

```
class CUSTOM_ObjectProps(PropertyGroup):
    obj_ref: PointerProperty(
        name="Object",
        type=bpy.types.Object)

class CUSTOM_NameProps(PropertyGroup):
    object_collection: CollectionProperty(
        name = "Object Collection",
        type = CUSTOM_ObjectProps)

class CUSTOM_SceneProps(PropertyGroup):
    user_collection: CollectionProperty(
        name = "Name Collection",
        type = CUSTOM_NameProps)

...
def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.ctm = PointerProperty(type=CUSTOM_SceneProps)
...
```

*Proof using the Console*

```
# Add User
>>> user = C.scene.ctm.user_collection.add()
>>> user.name = "Bob"
>>> user
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].ctm.user_collection[0]

>>> user_obj = C.scene.ctm.user_collection[0].object_collection.add()
>>> user_obj.obj_ref = C.object
>>> user_obj.name = "My Object"
>>> user_obj
bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].ctm.user_collection[0].object_collection[0]

>>> user_obj.obj_ref
bpy.data.objects['Mball']
```

To speed up testing, operators for adding or *printing* the values might become handy:

```
class CUSTOM_OT_PrintOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "scene.ctm_print_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Print Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        scn = context.scene
        custom = scn.ctm
        lookup_dict = {}

        for uc, user in enumerate(custom.user_collection):
            print ("User Index: {}, Name: {}, Ref: {}".format(uc, user.name, user))

            for oc, obj in enumerate(user.object_collection):
                print ("-> Object {}, Ref {}".format(oc, obj))
                lookup_dict.setdefault(user, []).append(obj.obj_ref)

        # In case, dicts are nice
        print ("\nLookup:", lookup_dict)
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

*Proof using the Console*

```
>>> bpy.ops.scene.ctm_print_operator()
User Index: 0, Name: Bob, Ref: <bpy_struct, CUSTOM_NameProps("Bob")>
-> Object 0, Ref <bpy_struct, CUSTOM_ObjectProps("Bob_Mball")>
-> Object 1, Ref <bpy_struct, CUSTOM_ObjectProps("Bob_Icosphere")>

Lookup: {bpy.data.scenes['Scene'].ctm.user_collection[0]: [bpy.data.objects['Mball'], bpy.data.objects['Icosphere']]}
{'FINISHED'}
```

---

#### Drawing

Hardest part is getting both lists to `draw` properly. Since the actual names *(from the first list)* don't necessarily have to be *unique*, we obviously can not rely on any name value. One approach is introducing a custom index property to get track of the changes and keep it in sync *(required for `template_list` anyway)*.

[image]

```
class CUSTOM_NameProps(PropertyGroup):
    active_obj_index: IntProperty()
    object_collection: CollectionProperty(
        name = "Object Collection",
        type = CUSTOM_ObjectProps)

user = custom.user_collection[custom.active_user_index]

...

layout.row().template_list(
    listtype_name = "CUSTOM_UL_Sub",
    list_id = "", 
    dataptr = user,
    propname = "object_collection",
    active_dataptr = user,
    active_propname = "active_obj_index",
    rows = min_rows
    )
```

*Notice*, when using the *wrong index* value pointing to any non existing item will raise exceptions.