# UIList to draw another UIList (Sub List) under the first UIList

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

I have been making an addon which requires me to have a UIList Item and have several items under that  UIList (Sub Items). I was thinking of having two UILists but I am not sure how to implement a draw function or whether that functionality is supported by blender.

I am looking to make something like this,

[image: UIList Item with Sub Items]

Appriciate if someone can help me with this.

Comment: AFAIK it is not yet possible to nest UILists  Consider outer items as subpanels..

Comment: Not possible to draw yet. You can have a second list in the same layout though: [How to get one UIList to control the contents of another UIList?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/159353/3710)

Comment: @batFINGER Thank you for your comment. I will shift my focus in to Panels.

Comment: @p2or Thank you for the link. I will look into it.