# How to create a dynamic UI-list similar to the outliner

Tags: python, scripting, outliner, interface

I'm currently trying to create sort of a "navigation" UI list with the parent/child concept like the outliner or any classic folder navigation.
But I'm stuck at the part where I need my items to be **dynamically hidden**.

the problem is that this kind (`if close: return`) of code won't actually hide the drawing of an element, as the element will still be drawn

```
class EXAMPLE_UL_folder_navigation(bpy.types.UIList):

    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):

        if not item:
            return 

        wm = bpy.context.window_manager
        if (item.parent!="") and not wm.scatter5.folder_navigation[item.parent].is_open:
            return  
            #Element will still be drawn, in an empty row
        
        #draw the row 
        row = layout.row(align=True)    

        row.separator(factor=item.level*2)

        row.prop(item,"is_open",icon="TRIA_DOWN" if item.is_open else "TRIA_RIGHT", icon_only=True, emboss=False)

        row.label(text=os.path.basename(item.name))
```

[image]

In my code I try to re-create folders structure, here's a sample of how I get the structure

```
Mapping = []

def recur_dir_mapping(path, level=0, parent=""):


    global Mapping

    Mapping.append({
        "is_folder":True,
        "name":os.path.basename(path),
        "path":path,
        "level": level if (level==0) else level-1,
        "parent":parent,
        })

    for p in os.listdir(path): #order of list generated by listdir is important..
        p = os.path.join(path,p)

        if os.path.isfile(p):

                Mapping.append({
                    "is_folder":False,
                    "name":os.path.basename(p),
                    "path":p,
                    "level":level,
                    "parent":path,
                    })

        elif os.path.isdir(p):
            recur_dir_mapping(p, level=level+1, parent=path)

    return None
```

and then how I create my UI list

```
        for i in range(len(collection_prop)):
            collection_prop.remove(0)

        recur_dir_mapping( mypath )
        global Mapping

        for element in Mapping:

            #library navigation = every folder & files 
            e = collection_prop.add()
            e.name      = element["name"]
            e.path      = element["path"]
            e.parent    = element["parent"]
            e.is_folder = element["is_folder"]


        #Reset Mapping
        Mapping = []
```

But this is the easy part,
the hard part is to truly "hide" elements dynamically, such as suggested in the gif above  similar to the outliner

[image]

I'm sure this has been done many times in the past right? Maybe UI lists aren't a wise choice for such dynamic drawing

Comment: This thread has similar functionality similar to your needs. https://blenderartists.org/t/blender-treelist-expanding-subelements-ui/1191260

Comment: Consider using  dynamically registered panels.

Comment: Agree with batFINGER, alternatively consider using a 2d list eg. [How to get one UIList to control the contents of another UIList?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158440/how-to-get-one-uilist-to-control-the-contents-of-another-uilist/)