# Dynamic list of properties for each property in Collection

Tags: python, scripting

I have a collection property called "Scenes", stored in the scene with some custom properties in it, displayed as a list in the panel,
My question is, can I have a separate list, unique to each "Scenes" entry, called for example "Dates" and define in it string properties dynamically, so the user can add date properties for each scene in the "Scene" collection property?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, collection properties can be nested. Can you add a little bit of your script so we know where to start from ?

Comment: So far I'm using the one I found here: https://sinestesia.co/blog/tutorials/amazing-uilists-in-blender/

Comment: Check this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/158440/how-to-get-one-uilist-to-control-the-contents-of-another-uilist/

Comment: Yes! Thank you all!