# How to access a property in a group property in the body of the script?

Tags: python, scripting, properties

I defined a class group property with some props inside and did the register and unregister with a pointer, but in the main body of the script how do you access the properties inside the group property?

Note: I can define a scene property and modify the value but cannot do it with a property from the group property.

Any add-on example showing how to do this would be nice too!

Comment: That's explained [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447) and there is an add-on example as well...

Comment: Always a good idea to post a script, rather than a description of script.

Comment: nice tut on UI design but did not show how to access prop from a groupProperty in the main part of a script

Comment: See "WM_OT_HelloWorld" operator in the template and *All in one* section.