# Pass data between panels and operators

Tags: python, scripting, operator, panel

How can I pass data from operator to another operator in one panel?
Specifically I have a dialog box, I want to get back the path of the selected box to a label and activate another operator(button)
Thanks

Comment: Please add your code to the question... and preferably a more detailed description of what you want. **I guess** what you want is a property group: See *All in One* section of [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/57306/31447). Also please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I realized how to use properties and  register them to access them from other classes/methods. This is probably also explained somewhere else. I was new to blender api. This can get closed also!