# Giving an object a color in an AddOn

Tags: python, add-on, color

Hello i want to create an AddOn in Blender. I'm working with visual studio code. I'm kinda new to this so my problem is that i want to have a label called "color" in my addon. In that label i want to give or change the color of my object. I don't know how to start or know the keywords/methods i need to use to change the color of an object.
Can somebody help me?
For the start it would be enough for me if i just could choose between the colors red, blue and yellow

I'm sorry if this seems like as if i just want to have the code but i have like zero programming skills and i searched for days for tutorials that could help me but i coudn't find one or i didn't understand them. So i would really appreciate it, if someone could help me with my problem.

```py
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout

    Color_Stones = layout.box()
    Color_Stones.label(text="Color")
```

Comment: AFAIK, coloring a label is not exposed to the API.

Comment: sorry i meant that a want to color my object in my addon. I only have written this: Color_Stones = layout.box()
        Color_Stones.label(text="Color")
now i want to color my object into blue, red or yellow but i don't have a clue how to do that

Comment: Please take your time and edit the question. Consider that the colour is determined by a shader. I'd suggest try to achieve it manually at first to get all tiny bits you might need. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask ...keywords, methods and such you can find here: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)

Comment: thank you but i still dont know how to give my objects colors

Comment: No problem. Again: depends on the shader. How does your shader look like? It's always the same shader?