# Drawing Float Property

Tags: python, scripting, materials, properties

I needed a Help in Drawing a Property Group,
I created a Color ramp in Line 78 and needed Control for the Slider and for that I assigned this to the *position_control* in line number 85.
and I wanted to draw the Slider of that position Control and I tried following [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui) to create this

I just Made the Class for Float Value but perhaps I am facing the Issue in Registering at the end as I don't know how to do this as this error is shown -

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "\TEST_MATERIAL.py", line
> 158, in  AttributeError: ramp_pos Error: Python script failed,
> check the message in the system console

Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
bl_info = {
"name": "Add Test Material",
"author": "Rakesh Choudhary",
"version": (1, 0),
"blender": (2, 83, 0),
"location": "View3D > Sidebar > Test Material Node",
"description": "Click on the 'Test Material' button to add a material to your object.",
"warning": "",
"wiki_url": "",
"category": "3D View"
}

import bpy
from bpy.types import (
    Operator,
    Panel,
    PropertyGroup,
)
from bpy.props import (
    FloatProperty,
    PointerProperty,
)


class TEST_MATERIAL_OT_add_material(Operator):
    bl_idname = "test_material.add_material"
    bl_label = "Add Test Material"
    bl_description = "This button will add a material to your object"

    def execute(self, context):
        self.create_material()
        return {'FINISHED'}

    def create_material(self):
        test_shader_mat = bpy.data.materials.new("TestMat")
        mesh = bpy.context.object.data
        mesh.materials.clear()
        mesh.materials.append(test_shader_mat)
        bpy.context.object.active_material.use_nodes = True

        for mat in bpy.data.materials:
            if "TestMat" in mat.name:
                nodes = mat.node_tree.nodes
                for node in nodes:
                    if node.type != 'OUTPUT_MATERIAL':  # skip the material output node as we'll need it later
                        nodes.remove(node)

        # Creating Node Group Test_Material
        group = bpy.data.node_groups.new(type="ShaderNodeTree", name="Test_Material")

        # Creating Group Input
        group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Diffuse Color")
        group.inputs.new("NodeSocketColor", "Glossy Color")
        group.inputs.new("NodeSocketFloat", "Glossyness")
        input_node = group.nodes.new("NodeGroupInput")
        input_node.location = (-800, 0)

        # Creating Group Output Node
        group.outputs.new("NodeSocketShader", "Diffuse Color")
        group.outputs.new("NodeSocketShader", "Glossy Color")
        group.outputs.new("NodeSocketShader", "Mix Output")

        output_node = group.nodes.new("NodeGroupOutput")
        output_node.location = (1500, 0)

        # Creating Diffuse Node
        diffuse_node = group.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
        diffuse_node.location = (150, 100)

        # Creating Glossy Node
        glossy_node = group.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeBsdfGlossy')
        glossy_node.location = (300, 250)

        # Creating Mix Shader Node
        mix_shader_node = group.nodes.new(type='ShaderNodeMixShader')
        mix_shader_node.location = (450, 100)
    
        #Creating Color Ramp
        col_ramp = group.nodes.new(type="ShaderNodeValToRGB")
        col_ramp.location = (400, -300)
        col_ramp.color_ramp.elements.remove(col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0])
    
        col_ramp.color_ramp.elements.new(0.750)
        col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].color = (0,0,0,1)
    
        position_control = col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].position


        col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].position = (1.0)
        col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[1].color = (1, 1, 1, 1)
    

        # Creating Links Between Nodes
        group.links.new(diffuse_node.outputs["BSDF"], mix_shader_node.inputs[1])
        group.links.new(glossy_node.outputs["BSDF"], mix_shader_node.inputs[2])
        group.links.new(input_node.outputs["Diffuse Color"], diffuse_node.inputs[0])
        group.links.new(input_node.outputs["Glossy Color"], glossy_node.inputs[0])
        group.links.new(input_node.outputs["Glossyness"], glossy_node.inputs[1])
        group.links.new(output_node.inputs["Diffuse Color"], diffuse_node.outputs[0])
        group.links.new(output_node.inputs["Glossy Color"], glossy_node.outputs[0])
        group.links.new(output_node.inputs["Mix Output"], mix_shader_node.outputs[0])
        group.links.new(col_ramp.outputs["Color"], mix_shader_node.inputs[0])

        # Putting Node Group to the node editor
        tree = bpy.context.object.active_material.node_tree
        group_node = tree.nodes.new("ShaderNodeGroup")
        group_node.node_tree = group
        group_node.location = (-40, 300)
        group_node.use_custom_color = True
        group_node.color = (1, 0.341, 0.034)
        group_node.width = 250

        shader_node_output_material_node = tree.nodes["Material Output"]
        links = tree.links
        links.new(group_node.outputs[0], shader_node_output_material_node.inputs[0])
    
class Col_ramp_Property(PropertyGroup):
   ramp_pos : FloatProperty(
       name = "Position",
       description = "A float property",
       default = 0.75,
       min = 0.01,
       max = 1.0
    )



class TEST_MATERIAL_PT_layout_panel(Panel):
    bl_label = "Test Material Node"
    bl_category = "Test Material"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        C = bpy.context
        position_control = C.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].position
        layout.operator("test_material.add_material", icon='IMPORT')
        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(position_control, "ramp_pos")


classes = (TEST_MATERIAL_OT_add_material, Col_ramp_Property, TEST_MATERIAL_PT_layout_panel)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.ramp_pos = PointerProperty(type=Col_ramp_Property)

    

def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.ramp_pos


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I set `C = bpy.context`

```
position_control = C.active_object.active_material.node_tree.nodes.col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].position
```

and still there is the same problem, I think the main problem is I couldn't find the correct path to(how to access) the colorramp's element's position

[image]

Comment: You're missing the import for the [`PointerProperty`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.PointerProperty.html). Also the code is not properly indented, the assignment and deletion aren't part of the `register()` and `unregister()` function.

Comment: @RobertGützkow Thanks for answering, I edited the Question and Imported the PointerProperty and also Indented the code but still giving that error - ValueError: bpy_struct "Col_ramp_Property" registration error: ramp_pos could not register

Comment: You're assigning strings to values that should be floats (default, min, max).

Comment: Here https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui this thing(default, min, max) are done this way only and now blender is showing this error - 'RNA_Types' object has no attribute 'ramp_pos' Error: Python script failed, check the message in the system console

Comment: Read Robert's comment carefully. One obvious issue: "Col_ramp_Property" is a *string* right? ...and you actually have to assign a *class* type... Again, recommend to take a basic python course.

Comment: How is it a String? Under the Class, I have defined - ramp_pos : FloatProperty Can you Please tell me how to assign class type or how will this problem be solved as I wanted to take the position of element of color ramp and draw that in panel

Comment: Try to understand what you're doing. You are assigning a *string* to `type`: `type="Col_ramp_Property"`. Assign the actual *class* type: `type=Col_ramp_Property`. Do you get the difference now?

Comment: @brockmann Thanks for your answer and after solving this a new error is there and this time it is - AttributeError: ramp_pos

Comment: I guess complete error message is: `position_control` has no attribute `ramp_pos`. Question is: Where `position_control` *variable* comes from? Not declared in the panel class...

Comment: Error is Just that much only AttributeError: ramp_pos But I agree that the problem may be in the `position_control` variable actually I have declared that above `position_control = col_ramp.color_ramp.elements[0].position` But I don't know how to declare it in Panel as I don't know the path to the color ramp element.

Comment: Have a look how this is done over [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447) in `OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel` class.

Comment: @brockmann thanks again for the reply I have already read that before but still, I read that again and I found my Mistake and Now I have added that to the Panel but actually now the Problem is I couldn't access the color ramp. Could you tell me please, how do I access them as the material(the color ramp is defined in it ). as the material will only be created when the operator will be called from the panel. so what is the right way to do this?

Comment: Please don't change your question each time - Imagine someone is already writing an answer (at the moment) and you are changing the question that drastically, it's a waste of time and not fair. This also means that if you can draw the property, we are done here IMHO. I suggest ask a new question on how to do... @Rakeshchoudhary

Comment: @brockmann Ok, thank you very much I am going to ask a new question for this problem.

Comment: ... and you don't "found the mistake" -> this: `C = bpy.context` in combination with `position_control = C.active_object...` within an operator method is no good. First of all, you already have `context`, use it! Next, If you had read the contents of `OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel` in the answer I suggested you should now that you need a reference to the PointerProperty (`Scene.ramp_pos`) so it is `mytool = context.scene.ramp_pos` and then `row.prop(mytool, "ramp_pos")`. confusing to read due to your naming.

Comment: @brockmaan  thanks for answering I tried this but it is still giving an error. I think the problem I am facing is in accessing the color ramp's element's position. So I have asked a new question with some clarity- https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/183147/accessing-nodes-in-a-node-group-to-draw-property-in-panel