# Basic concept question of Scripting

Tags: scripting

What does **class** here mean?

Does it mean blender will use this class as blueprint to create a instance object of `bpy.types.Panel`?

(I'm new to python and blender scripting.)

[image]

Comment: Please post code as text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntax `class DerivedClassName(BaseClassName):` is for declaring a class `DerivedClassName` that inherits from `BaseClassName`. In the case of your code example `VIEW3D_PT_monkey_grid` inherits from `bpy.types.Panel`. More information about Python's syntax and concepts can be found in its [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#inheritance).

The code does not instantiate an object from the class, it only declares the class. In order to use the panel `VIEW3D_PT_monkey_grid` you will have to register/unregister it in the `register`/`unregister` function. This is how objects for UI elements are instantiated in Blender.

[This answer by p2or](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/74827) should give you a complete overview of UI creation through Blender's Python API.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the docs.