# Why is my own add-on not showing in the Preferences panel when installed?

Tags: scripting, add-on

I made a super-simple, one script add-on that duplicates objects and moves them to a hidden 'Backups' collection. It installs and works fine, but for reasons unknown to me does not show up in the Add-Ons panel in preferences. I have a bl_info object in my script:

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Quick Backup",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Object",
    "location": "Tools (N key) > QuickBackup Tab"
    "description": "Create a duplicate of selected objects and move it a Backups collection. The button will make a Backups collection if one doesn't exist"
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, there is a spelling error in the dict you provided. You forgot to add a comma after the location entry: `"location": "Path to the tool",`.

Comment: This was the problem, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bare minimum is adding a `register()` function, otherwise it won't install. Also `bl_info` dict has to be formatted properly, make sure the entries are separated by a `,`. Easy to test using our famous *Operator Simple* template *(Text Editor > Templates > Python > Operator Simple)*

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Your Add-on Name",
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "category": "Object"
}

import bpy

'''
class SimpleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        pass
        return {'FINISHED'}
'''

def register():
    pass
    #bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)


def unregister():
    pass
    #bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Further reading:

- [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)
- https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html