# Looking for pyqt combobox and listwidget equivalents in blender

Tags: python, scripting, interface

I need to port a tool from nuke (to blender).  The nuke tool uses pyqt comboboxes and listwidgets.  The widgets are populated with info from an external database.  The widgets are displayed vertically.

production [combobox] <- list of productions
sequence [combobox] <- list of sequences in a selected production
shot [combobox] <- list of shots in a selected sequence
assets [listwiget] <- list of assets in a selected shot

When a selection is made in one of the comboboxes, the subsequent widgets are updated.  Ultimately, I extract the list of selected assets from the listwidget at the bottom.

Is it possible to make multiple selections with an UIList?

Comment: Hi and welcome! Related q/a: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447) Please edit your question and ask only 1 question per post to make this q/a useful to future visitors. Recommend take the tour to learn about how this site works: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour, also see https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask Thanks. -> *In short:* (1) Yes (2) update callback (3) Yes, no other option (4) Yes (5) Yes (6) No However, explaining all of that as well as providing some code examples, the answer section would explode as you might guess...

Comment: @brockmann if you type "tour" between brackets ( [  tour   ], with no spaces) it will automatically generate a link to the [tour], same as the [edit] link, to generate a link to edit the question.