# Toggle Box UI In Panel

Tags: scripting, interface, light, panel

[image: My Light Group]

The above image is what I have created so far, still prototyping, just got started scripting within Blender

Would like to be able to collapse each box, which contains light properties, like the image below (from Luxcore).
Does Blender have this option or do I have to build it from scratch?

[image: Light Group]

I have looked through the code, but can't seem to make sense of it...

Comment: Also I'd recommend have a look into: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/57332#57332)

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I have been looking for :D