# Choosing right context for property in viewport panel

Tags: properties, panel

I have a simple panel that you can see in the viewport which is a shorter version of *UI Panel Simple*.
Seeing from other panels, by using *Edit Source*, they all define a context where the property is added, but how do I decide which one to use to get it working?
Using Blender 2.92.

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = "Tool"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')


class QuickRename_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Quick Rename"
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_hello"

    testBool: BoolProperty(
        name = 'Test',
        description = 'Test description',
        default = True,)


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False

        tool_settings = context.tool_settings

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(tool_settings, 'testBool')



def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(QuickRename_PT_Panel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(QuickRename_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

I want to add the testBool property to the Hello World Panel.
[image]

But I think the

```
tool_settings = context.tool_settings
```

is wrong.

Comment: We do not declare properties in panel classes. Either use a property group or register your property directly to the scene: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Comment: or AFAIK also not on any non ID types (those in bpy.data collections like Objects, and bones)   _eg_  `bpy.types.ToolSettings.test_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty()` then  in python console type in  `C.tool_settings.test_bool`  If it is not `True or False` '  can't do it.

Comment: Yes, thats why I added the answer with the link to How to create a custom UI? and working code

Answer (score 0):

Okay by looking at [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui) I could figure it out

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty, PointerProperty
from bpy.types import PropertyGroup

class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'Tool'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.label(text="Hello world!", icon='WORLD_DATA')


class QuickRenameProperties(PropertyGroup):
    test_bool: BoolProperty(
        name = 'Test',
        description = 'Test description',
        default = True)


class QuickRename_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_label = "Quick Rename"
    bl_category = "Tool"
    bl_parent_id = "OBJECT_PT_hello"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.use_property_split = True
        layout.use_property_decorate = False
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        row = layout.row()
        row.prop(mytool, 'test_bool')


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(QuickRename_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(QuickRenameProperties)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type = QuickRenameProperties)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(QuickRename_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```