# How to make a button link to a DataLibrary using python?

Tags: python, import, append, library

I have a random 3D model from a .blend file and I have been using Blenders Data Libraries to import it.

Here is the code:

```
import bpy


filepath = r"C:\\path\example.blend"

coll_name = "collection name"

link = False

with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
    data_to.collections = [c for c in data_from.collections if c.startswith(coll_name)]

for coll in data_to.collections:
    if coll is not None:
       bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)
```

It imports my object I need. But I would like to be able to press a button to activate it. So how can I do that?

I want the button to look like this:

[image]

(That type of formatting)

### -

- 

If you have any questions, please let me know and I will reply as soon as I can.

Thanks
Daniel

Comment: You'd have to "convert" your code into an operator to get a button. Recommend read: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i took the liberty to make an addon out of it.

It's a bit convoluted, so i made the simple version and EXTRA with file picker, it's mostly from
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9fuFDHR-UkE&list=PLa1F2ddGya_8acrgoQr1fTeIuQtkSd6BW&index=6

it adds a panel default 'N' key
the panel can be merged with existing panels by modifying `bl_category`

just create a file in your blender instal folder /Version Nr/Scripts/Addons/
name it anything.py

then in blender after a restart go to preference/addons search for "Link data" and enable it.

hope that saves you a headache. hehe

```
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Link to Data Library",
    "author" : "Daniel",
    "description" : "Add description Here",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "location" : "",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_link_data(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tool tip thingy"""
    bl_label = "Link Data"
    bl_idname = "object.link_data"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def execute(self, context):

        filepath = r"C:\\path\example.blend"

        coll_name = "collection name"

        link = False

        with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections = [c for c in data_from.collections if c.startswith(coll_name)]

        for coll in data_to.collections:
            if coll is not None:
               bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)

        return {"FINISHED"}

class VIEW3D_PT_Link_Data(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Tool tip thingy"""
    bl_label = "Link To Data"
    bl_category = "Link Data"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column()

        col.operator("OBJECT_OT_link_data",
            text="link data",
            icon="PACKAGE"
        )


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_link_data)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Link_Data)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_link_data)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Link_Data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Modified version with EXTRA bits

````
bl_info = {
    "name" : "Link to Data Library",
    "author" : "Daniel",
    "description" : "Add description Here",
    "blender" : (2, 80, 0),
    "version" : (0, 0, 1),
    "location" : "",
    "warning" : "",
    "category" : "Generic"
}

import bpy

class OBJECT_OT_link_data(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tool tip thingy"""
    bl_label = "Link Data"
    bl_idname = "object.link_data"
    bl_options = {"REGISTER", "UNDO"}
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def execute(self, context):

        filepath = bpy.path.abspath(context.scene.DanielLinkFile)

        coll_name = context.scene.DanielLinkCollection

        link = context.scene.DanielLink

        with bpy.data.libraries.load(filepath, link=link) as (data_from, data_to):
            data_to.collections = [c for c in data_from.collections if c.startswith(coll_name)]

        for coll in data_to.collections:
            if coll is not None:
               bpy.context.scene.collection.children.link(coll)

        return {"FINISHED"}

class VIEW3D_PT_Link_Data(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Tool tip thingy"""
    bl_label = "Link To Data"
    bl_category = "Link Data"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_context = "objectmode"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        col = layout.column()

        col.prop(context.scene, "DanielLinkFile")
        col.prop(context.scene, "DanielLinkCollection")
        col.prop(context.scene, "DanielLink")

        col.operator("OBJECT_OT_link_data",
            text="link data",
            icon="PACKAGE"
        )


def register():
    bpy.types.Scene.DanielLinkFile = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Link File",subtype="FILE_PATH", default=r"C:\\path\example.blend")
    bpy.types.Scene.DanielLinkCollection = bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Link Collection",default="collection name")
    bpy.types.Scene.DanielLink = bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Link",default=False)

    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_OT_link_data)
    bpy.utils.register_class(VIEW3D_PT_Link_Data)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.Scene.DanielLinkFile
    del bpy.types.Scene.DanielLinkCollection
    del bpy.types.Scene.DanielLink
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_OT_link_data)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(VIEW3D_PT_Link_Data)



if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()

```
````

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the exact answer I was looking for!