# A button that revert the current .blend

Tags: scripting, blend-files

How can I create a button that calls "bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile()" when pressed?

Comment: Where the button should live? Please add a bit more context. Related or dupe: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the *identifier* of the operator to [`UILayout.operator(operator_identifier)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=layout%20operator#bpy.types.UILayout.operator). Example based on the *Panel Simple* template that comes with Blender (adds a panel to the *Object Properties*):

[image]

```
import bpy


class HelloWorldPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    """Creates a Panel in the Object properties window"""
    bl_label = "Hello World Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_hello"
    bl_space_type = 'PROPERTIES'
    bl_region_type = 'WINDOW'
    bl_context = "object"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        row = layout.row()            
        row.operator("wm.revert_mainfile")


def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(HelloWorldPanel)


def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(HelloWorldPanel)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Further reading: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/)**