Making addon scrip
Try to make a simple addon for the blender. It should add a 3d person-like movement for the object.
The addon has appeared in tabs, but when I press the button nothing happens
here is my scene 
and pyton script:
bl_info = {
"name": "Simple Third Person Shooter Addon",
"blender": (3, 0, 0),  # Adjust according to your Blender version
"category": "Object",
"version": (1, 0, 1),
"author": "Your Name",
"description": "Addon to simulate a third-person shooter with basic movement, jumping, and crouching mechanics.",
}

import bpy
from mathutils import Vector

class SimpleTPSOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Operator to run TPS Simulation"""
    bl_idname = "wm.run_tps_simulation"
    bl_label = "Run TPS Simulation"

    _timer = None
    move_speed = 0.1
    rotation_speed = 0.05
    jump_strength = 0.2
    crouch_height = 0.5
    normal_height = 2.0
    is_crouching = False
    on_ground = True  # Simple check for whether the character is on the ground

    def modal(self, context, event):
        character_obj = bpy.data.objects.get('Character')
        camera_obj = bpy.data.objects.get('Camera')

        if not character_obj or not camera_obj:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Required objects (Character, Camera) not found.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        # Handle movement
        if event.type == 'W' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            character_obj.location.y += self.move_speed
        elif event.type == 'S' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            character_obj.location.y -= self.move_speed
        elif event.type == 'A' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            character_obj.rotation_euler.z += self.rotation_speed
        elif event.type == 'D' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            character_obj.rotation_euler.z -= self.rotation_speed

        # Handle jumping
        if event.type == 'SPACE' and event.value == 'PRESS' and self.on_ground:
            character_obj.location.z += self.jump_strength
            self.on_ground = False

        # Simulate gravity for jumping
        if character_obj.location.z > self.normal_height:
            character_obj.location.z -= 0.01
        else:
            self.on_ground = True

        # Handle crouching
        if event.type == 'LEFT_CTRL' and event.value == 'PRESS':
            character_obj.scale.z = self.crouch_height
            self.is_crouching = True
        elif event.type == 'LEFT_CTRL' and event.value == 'RELEASE':
            character_obj.scale.z = self.normal_height
            self.is_crouching = False

        if event.type == 'ESC':
            self.cancel(context)
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

    def execute(self, context):
        context.window_manager.modal_handler_add(self)
        return {'RUNNING_MODAL'}

    def cancel(self, context):
        wm = context.window_manager
        if self._timer:
            wm.event_timer_remove(self._timer)
        self.report({'INFO'}, "TPS simulation stopped.")
        return {'CANCELLED'}

class TPS_PT_MainPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Third Person Shooter Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_tps_panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'
    bl_category = 'TPS'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        row = layout.row()
        row.operator("wm.run_tps_simulation")

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleTPSOperator)
    bpy.utils.register_class(TPS_PT_MainPanel)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleTPSOperator)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(TPS_PT_MainPanel)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


Hello and welcome. Here's a simple addon on how to print "Hello World" on button click. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/229533/i-need-help-making-my-first-hello-world-addon-adding-a-button-with-a-function

It works(from object mode obviously - it's edit mode in the sceenshot), but it conflicts with default hotkeys. Maybe should not use return {'PASS_THROUGH'}

Hello and welcome. Please use a title that matches the content of the post. It should read like a question, be descriptive but succinct, unique and identifying, summarizing the problem so that anyone searching for similar issues is likely to find this. Remove anything superfluous, avoid using words like "this", "help with", "issue" or "question about", instead describe what "it" is. Remember, your title is the first thing visitors see, answers you get depend heavily on it. See What is the problem of asking “How do I do this?"

I would recommend using a game engine for this application. It's probably possible to do in Blender but why make things difficult for yourself? Godot is pretty approachable, Unreal is a bit less beginner friendly but you can do anything in there. Unless I don't understand your goals.
