# How to make that neat UI for my rig like Rain from Blender Cloud

Tags: rigging

I made rig on my own. Didn't use rigify or any other addon, just did it myself. Now when my rig is finished, I wonder, can I make that rig control like for example Rain from blender cloud rig control - with layers(FK, IK, Hair, fingers etc.) then those FK/IK switch and so on.

Comment: The UI is written in python. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are (at least) three ways to get a good rig control panel, and I suspect you would be best served using the second way:

1. Build your rig with a rigging tool like rigify that generates its own rigging panel.
2. Use a rigging layers management add-on like [Bone Layer Manager](https://fin.gumroad.com/l/STdb)
3. Write your own python script to create and manage a UI.

Bone Layer Manager is a free add-on that allows you to build your own rig UI that is similar to that created automatically by rigify.  It's pretty easy to learn how to use and there are tutorials.