# Creating a row of boolean properties (with icons) aligned in a UI panel

Tags: python, interface, properties

Is it possible to do this within a bpy API - a set of boolean properties where multiple can be selected, with their own icons, right next to each other like below (from the outliner filter):

[image: Row of adjacent toggles with individual icons]

Whenever I try row(align=True) or grid_flow(align=True) with multiple boolean properties, there's still a padding/margin between them:

[image: multiple boolean properties with space between them]

Is there a way to do this with individual booleans or boolean vector properties?

Here's a sample of the code (the variables are BoolProperty type):

```
def draw(self, context):
    layout = self.layout
    scene = context.scene

    layout.use_property_split = True

    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(scene, 'v_name',
             icon='RESTRICT_SELECT_OFF', icon_only=True)
    row.prop(scene, 'v_name2',
             icon='HIDE_OFF', icon_only=True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although `align=True` is usually the issue, I figured out it was `UILayout.use_property_split` in this case. I set it to "False" for the row itself and it worked as expected.

Edit: `UILayout.use_property_decorate` specifically adds the space for the keyframe button - I explicitly prevented these props from being animateable, so the decoration didn't show up. But the space was still made. So disabling this property also works.

Comment: You can also enable `UILayout.use_property_split` but disable `UILayout.use_property_decorate`. If I set `use_property_split` to true (in code above) I get these dots in between the elements: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZyDKD.png (I think the screenshot in your question would look way different... Doesn't it?). Glad you have found the bug - however, impossible to guess based on your question IMHO.

Comment: @brockmann thank you for that - that also works. I had set my props to not be animateable, but it spaces them anyway even if they aren't visually decorated. I'll add that as well.

Comment: No problem. Can not confirm, no spaces here, looks like the same as without split enabled. Added as option to the demo so you can test it.

Comment: IMO since the default is False https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_split the issue was that you set it to True, making question a bit like _"There's something wrong with my dog, ... trick question it's a cat"_  Please always add all relevant code to questions in future.

Comment: @batFINGER will do. I know that's my bad in not sharing enough information :/

Answer (score 4):

Just pass `align=True` when calling the encapsulating layout element like [`UILayout.row(align=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=row#bpy.types.UILayout.row), [`UILayout.column(align=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=row#bpy.types.UILayout.column), or [`UILayout.grid_flow(align=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=row#bpy.types.UILayout.grid_flow) to get rid of the padding:

```
    ...
    layout = self.layout
    row = layout.row(align=True)
    row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CAMERA_DATA', text="")
    row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CONSOLE', text="")
    row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='ARMATURE_DATA', text="")
    ...
```

Demo based on the template from [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)

[image]

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add-on Template",
    "author": "p2or, brockmann",
    "version": (0, 0, 3),
    "blender": (2, 80, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Tools",
    "category": "Development"
}


import bpy

from bpy.props import BoolProperty, PointerProperty
from bpy.types import Panel, PropertyGroup

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Scene Properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MyProperties(PropertyGroup):

    my_bool: BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_custom_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        
        # layout.use_property_split = True
        # layout.use_property_decorate = False

        row = layout.row(align=True)
        row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CAMERA_DATA', text="")
        row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CONSOLE', text="")
        row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='ARMATURE_DATA', text="")
        row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='OUTLINER_OB_LIGHT', text="")
        row.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='BOLD', text="")
        
        grid = layout.grid_flow(columns=5, align=True)
        grid.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CAMERA_DATA', text="")
        grid.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CONSOLE', text="")
        grid.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='ARMATURE_DATA', text="")
        grid.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='BOLD', text="")
        
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CAMERA_DATA', text="")
        col.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='CONSOLE', text="")
        col.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='ARMATURE_DATA', text="")
        col.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='OUTLINER_OB_LIGHT', text="")
        col.prop(mytool, "my_bool", icon='BOLD', text="")
        
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

classes = (
    MyProperties,
    OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel
)

def register():
    from bpy.utils import register_class
    for cls in classes:
        register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)

def unregister():
    from bpy.utils import unregister_class
    for cls in reversed(classes):
        unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

**Note:** If you'd like to use [`UILayout.use_property_split`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=use_property_split#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_split), make sure you set [`layout.use_property_decorate`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.UILayout.html?highlight=use_property_split#bpy.types.UILayout.use_property_decorate) to `False`, otherwise the panel will look like:

[image]

Comment: I had "align=True" in my case. Updated post with code sample.