# Create a next button inside panel

Tags: python, scripting

I was working with the addon but I have stuck at this situation. I want to press the `Next` button inside panel then, new operators should pop up and the rest operators should be removed. Basically, I want to know how does `Next` button work.

There is a better example in the screenshots to understand what I am looking for.

[image]
[image]

````
import bpy
C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data
O = bpy.ops

class ADDON_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Add Objects"
    bl_idname = "pl.add_mesh"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Add Objects"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator('meshes.delete_all')
        row=layout.row(align=True)
        row.operator('back.op')
        row.operator('next.op')
#        layout.operator('mesh.add_cube')
        
class NEXT_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Next"
    bl_idname = "next.op"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BACK_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Back"
    bl_idname = "back.op"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        return {'FINISHED'}

class ADD_OBJECTS(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Cube"
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_cube"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        O.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        C.object.modifiers.new('Subdividion','SUBSURF')
        return {'FINISHED'}


class DELETE_ALL(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Delete all objects"
    bl_idname = "meshes.delete_all"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}


classes = (ADDON_PANEL,  DELETE_ALL, NEXT_OP, BACK_OP, ADD_OBJECTS)
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```
````

Comment: Share the code along with the question

Answer (score 0):

I would use a custom property for the UI to store the page number ([How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui)). The *Next* button increases the number and the *Back* button decreases it. In the *draw* method, use the value to decide which buttons should be shown on the given page. The property is stored in the *scene*.

**Notes:** 
Beware that if there is an error in the *draw* method you only will see it in the *System Console*. There is no error popup.
If you have different independent [scenes](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/scene/introduction.html), there will be different options for your add-on in each scene.

[image: next and back buttons]

```
import bpy

from bpy.props import (StringProperty,
                       BoolProperty,
                       IntProperty,
                       FloatProperty,
                       FloatVectorProperty,
                       EnumProperty,
                       PointerProperty,
                       )
from bpy.types import (Panel,
                       Menu,
                       Operator,
                       PropertyGroup,
                       )

C = bpy.context
D = bpy.data
O = bpy.ops

class ADDON_PANEL(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Add Objects"
    bl_idname = "pl.add_mesh"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Add Objects"
    
    def draw(self,context):
        layout = self.layout
        layout.operator('meshes.delete_all')
        
        my_tool = context.scene.my_tool   # access to properties
        
        print('draw: my_tool.wizard_page_number -> ', my_tool.wizard_page_number)
        
        # decide what to draw on the current page
        row=layout.row(align=True)
        if my_tool.wizard_page_number > 0:
            row.operator('back.op')
        if my_tool.wizard_page_number < 3:
            row.operator('next.op')
        if my_tool.wizard_page_number == 1:
            layout.operator('mesh.add_cube')
            
        layout.prop(my_tool, "wizard_page_number")    
        
class NEXT_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Next"
    bl_idname = "next.op"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        my_tool = context.scene.my_tool   # access to properties
        my_tool.wizard_page_number += 1   # next page
        return {'FINISHED'}

class BACK_OP(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Back"
    bl_idname = "back.op"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        my_tool = context.scene.my_tool   # access to properties
        my_tool.wizard_page_number -= 1   # prev. page
        return {'FINISHED'}

class ADD_OBJECTS(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = "Add Cube"
    bl_idname = "mesh.add_cube"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        O.mesh.primitive_cube_add()
        C.object.modifiers.new('Subdividion','SUBSURF')
        return {'FINISHED'}


class DELETE_ALL(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_label = f"Delete all objects"
    bl_idname = "meshes.delete_all"
    
    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.delete(use_global=False, confirm=False)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Scene Properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
class MyProperties(PropertyGroup):

    wizard_page_number: IntProperty(
        name="Wizard Page Number",
        description="Current Page of the Wizard",
        default = 0
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
classes = (ADDON_PANEL,  DELETE_ALL, NEXT_OP, BACK_OP, ADD_OBJECTS, MyProperties)   # register MyProperties
def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = PointerProperty(type=MyProperties)    # store in scene
    
def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool                                     # delete from scene
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: That's really, helpful. Is there any way to do it without using properties?