# How do I create a drop-down menu with custom properties? (Blender 3.5)

Tags: rigging, custom-properties

I want to create a drop-down menu for my rig. I have this settings bone in it, in which I want to add something to change the subdivisions. I thought integers aren't that user-friendly, so what I thought would be a good idea is to make a drop down menu (a bit like a video game settings menu).

[image: (properties without the drop down feature)]

This drop down menu would allow you to change the quality of the rig along with the 3 options "Low", "Medium", and "High".

The thing is I don't really know how I would do this and I can't seem to find any answers online, so I'm completely stuck. What do I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create all kinds of custom UI elements through Python. This Stack Exchange post is one of the best I've seen on the topic:

[How to create a custom UI](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui).

Comment: would that work in a custom property though?