# How Can I Create Value Slider In Blender 3.6 With Python Api?

Tags: python, scripting, add-on

How can I create a value silder like dimensions panel in Blender 3.6 with Python Api.
I can already access dimension value and change those value with python script.
I have the code for my slider panel[image on the left] , but I want to make dimensions panel like sliders [X, Y, Z] with values.

[image: My Panel]
[image: Desired Panel]

Comment: Found my desired panel I was looking for at https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57306/how-to-create-a-custom-ui/128409#128409