# Add toggle hotkey to custom checkbox

Tags: python, scripting, interface, shortcut

I have a self made checkbox in a script. Now I want to create a hotkey in the Input manager to toggle it.

What I have done so far is to create a keymap item with `wm.context_toggle`. But I cannot get the Context Attribute to work. I grab the one from my script, the Python term in the tooltip. Which is `WindowManager.deselect_bool` and with that I get an error that the "Object has no attribute WindowManager".

What is the proper Context Attribute term here? Is it even possible to do it this way? If not, what is the proper way to assign a toggle hotkey for my custom checkbox?

Script:

```
import bpy
from bpy.props import BoolProperty

class LayoutDemoPanel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_label = "Demo Panel"
    bl_space_type = 'VIEW_3D'
    bl_region_type = 'UI'

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        wm = context.window_manager # Our bool is in the windows_manager
        layout.prop(wm, "deselect_bool") # Our checkbox

def register():
    bpy.types.WindowManager.deselect_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
    name="Checkbox", description="A checkbox", default = False)
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)

def unregister():
    del bpy.types.WindowManager.deselect_bool # Unregister our flag when unregister.
    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

[image]

Comment: The context attribute would be `window_ manager.deselect_bool`  `WindowManager` is the class of `context.window_manager`  Look in system console for error messages.

Comment: @batFINGER, thanks, but i get just another error message now, SyntaxError: invalid syntax. And no hint where. location: :-1

Comment: batFINGERs suggestion works for me when using your script, are you sure you don't have a typo somewhere? One thing that's strange however: The hotkey does work, but the checkbox is updated only if you put the mouse cursor into the panel where it lives in. Not sure if that really is the way to go

Comment: That's odd. I have copied and pasted the terms to avoid typoes. And as told, i get the upper error when i have the mouse over the 3D view. But thanks for your observation. When i have the mouse over the panel then i don't get the error message. But the checkbox doesn't toggle neither, which it does for you. What do we overlook here?

Comment: Ah, wasn't a good idea to copy the term from batFINGER's post. He had a gap in window_ manager. When i write window_manager then the error is gone. But still no toggle with the hotkey :(

Comment: Now i see what you mean with moving the mouse into the panel. I have to explicitely move the mouse over the checkbox to get it updated.

Well then, so the initial question is answered. Remains the part with updating the checkbox after the bool value has changed. Thanks a bunch everybody :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example based on [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/46848/how-to-toggle-visibilty-of-subsurf-modifier-using-shortcut/46864#46864). Once it's registered you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> to toggle your [BoolProperty](https://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.BoolProperty.html). **Also notice** that  tagging the area for a redraw via `context.area.tag_redraw()` is requiered after the assignment call in oder to  *update the Panel* properly:

[image]

Once it's enabled (or registered) the shortcut is created automatically:

[image]

**custom-toggle-shortcut.py**

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Add-on Template",
    "description": "",
    "author": "poor",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 70, 0),
    "location": "3D View > Tools",
    "warning": "", # used for warning icon and text in addons panel
    "wiki_url": "",
    "tracker_url": "",
    "category": "Development"
}

import bpy

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    my properties
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class MySettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    operators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class ToggleOperator(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "view3d.toggle_mybool"
    bl_label = "Toggle My Bool"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):  
        context.scene.my_tool.my_bool = not context.scene.my_tool.my_bool
        context.area.tag_redraw()
        return {'FINISHED'}


# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    my tool in objectmode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_my_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"    
    bl_context = "objectmode"   

    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool
        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#     register and unregister
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

addon_keymaps = []

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(ToggleOperator.bl_idname, type='Q', value='PRESS', shift=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

def unregister():

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/p2or/8a37617c4565e4ff143b736a0e4a1660

**Alternatively using an update method**

Rather than create a new operator use the `wm.context_toggle` operator, and set up an update method on the property that will redraw the area when run.  If the panel is in same area as key press then would only need `update=prop_update`

```
def prop_update(self, context):
    context.area.tag_redraw()
    return None
```

In example below `area_ui_update('VIEW_3D')` returns an update method  where if `area.type == 'VIEW_3D'` in screen.areas that area will redraw.  Useful when your panel is in an area other than context.area eg if your panel was in 'PROPERTIES' you would `area_ui_update('PROPERTIES')`

```
import bpy

def area_ui_update(type):
    ''' tag redraw on areas of type '''
    def ui_update(self, context):
        areas = [a for a in screen.areas if a.type == type]
        for a in areas:
            area.tag_redraw()
        return None
    return ui_update

class MySettings(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):

    my_bool = bpy.props.BoolProperty(
        name="Enable or Disable",
        description="A bool property",
        default = False,
        update=area_ui_update('VIEW_3D')
        )

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    my tool in objectmode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_my_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "OBJECT_PT_my_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"    
    bl_context = "objectmode"   

    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        scene = context.scene
        mytool = scene.my_tool

        layout.prop(mytool, "my_bool")

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
# register and unregister
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

addon_keymaps = []

# register
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_module(__name__)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_tool = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=MySettings)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.context_toggle", type='Q', value='PRESS', shift=True)
        kmi.properties.data_path = "scene.my_tool.my_bool"
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

# unregister
def unregister():

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_module(__name__)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_tool


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Hope you like new addition.

Comment: Very much. I'm still at investigating. Thank you both :)

Comment: One small problem is left. The Info editor does not display the changes to the bool. That happens just when you click the checkbox. Any ideas here? :)

Comment: As a funny sidenote, the code also works and updates the checkbox when i run def ui_update(self, context): without the for loop. Means without the tag_redraw. Just with return None and Return ui_update.

Comment: @Tiles That's normal behavior. Reflecting a bool change in the info area, only works when *clicking* a property or *calling an operator*. You can test this by your own - assign a shortcut to a existent bool property and you'll see that nothing shows up. Again, for simplicity I suggest use my Add-on template. You will see that the operator call shows up in the info area. Alternatively you can `report` any change in the info area, I updated the gist: https://gist.github.com/p2or/8a37617c4565e4ff143b736a0e4a1660, see line 43 and 46. More info here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/717/3710

Comment: Perfect. Now we have really everything :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer from batFINGER was the solution for the intial problem:

> The context attribute would be `window_manager.deselect_bool` `WindowManager` is the class of `context.window_manager` Look in system console for error messages. – batFINGER