# ''only render'' to bind as a hotkey

Tags: python, interface

how to put ''bpy.context.space_data.show_only_render = False/True'' as a key binding? I tried digging the python's API for an operator or identifier but could not find it. I just need the operator/identifier line to put in the field.

Comment: Related http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58486/add-toggle-hotkey-to-custom-checkbox?rq=1