# Scripted NodeFrame does not attach children until nodeview is updated

Tags: scripting, node-editor

This snippet can be run from Text Editor to get an idea of what I mean.

```
import bpy

nt = bpy.data.materials['Material'].node_tree
nodes = nt.nodes

a = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
a.location = 0, 0

b = nodes.new('ShaderNodeBsdfDiffuse')
b.location = 200, 0

f = nodes.new('NodeFrame')
f.location = -200, 0

a.parent = f
b.parent = f
```

That produces this initially.

[image]

only when i move the mouse inside the nodeview does the Frame update its visual representation.

[image]

I would love some suggestions. The code/Operator that we execute in Sverchok has the NodeView context and an edit_tree if that helps.

Comment: Have you tried to update your scene or tag your area

Comment: If the operator is executed within the right context, it will update automatically (without any issues), even without [tagging the area](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/58534/3710) to redraw: https://gist.github.com/p2or/b92d0859c68ac78673a2d0bedb2af09f Is your actual goal, running that from the text editor or another area?

Comment: @p2or i think your snippet works because you are calling `bpy.ops.node.add_node(bl_idname)`, my  script builds an entire nodetree using `nodes.new(bl_idname)`, which doesn't have the same scene update behaviour.

Comment: Updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/p2or/b92d0859c68ac78673a2d0bedb2af09f) using `new()`. Does that work for you? @zeffii

Comment: Ahh, now I get it. Updated the gist again. I think in this case adding `context.area.tag_redraw()` (as @J.Bakker suggested) does the trick @zeffii

Comment: weird. that doesn't snap the frame either. (until i move the cursor over the frame... which is the behaviour I started out with) . haha.. sorry I must be thick or something :)

Comment: You are right, that doesn't help updating the UI neither. For now I can't find a better way than adding `bpy.ops.node.select_all()` at the end... (updated again) @zeffii