# How do I make a hotkey that changes a property?

Tags: python, scripting, shortcut, properties

In my addon (Blender 2.8) I would like to have a hotkey that changes the value of a Property (to be exact: a BoolProperty which is a part of a PropertyGroup). I have found a way of doing this for an Operator, but I can't figure it out for the Property.

Properties [are mentioned](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.KeyMap.html#bpy.types.KeyMap.space_type) as a possible `space_type` for new keymaps, but it wasn't enough info to get me going. How can I achieve this?

The code I have right now does not work (i.e. the hotkey <kbd>1</kbd> is not executed):

```
import bpy

class FP_PT_user_panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "FP_PT_user_panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_label = "Test Prop"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.prop(context.scene.brush_properties, 'is_smooth_brush', text='[1]Smooth brush', toggle=True, icon="BRUSH_SMOOTH")


class BrushProperties(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    def smooth_brush_handler(mod, context):
        # some other stuff here #

        for a in [a for a in bpy.context.screen.areas if a.type == 'VIEW_3D']:
            a.tag_redraw()

    is_smooth_brush: bpy.props.BoolProperty(default=False, update=smooth_brush_handler)


addon_keymaps = []
classes = (
    FP_PT_user_panel,
    BrushProperties,
)


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)

    bpy.types.Scene.brush_properties = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type=BrushProperties)

    kcfg = bpy.context.window_manager.keyconfigs.addon
    if kcfg:
        km = kcfg.keymaps.new(name='3D View', space_type='VIEW_3D')
        items = []
        addon_keymaps.append((km, items))
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new("wm.context_toggle", type='ONE', value='PRESS')
        kmi.properties.data_path = "scene.brush_properties.is_smooth_brush"
        items.append(kmi)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)

    km, items = addon_keymaps.pop()
    for i in items:
        km.keymap_items.remove(i)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    del bpy.types.Scene.brush_properties


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58486/add-toggle-hotkey-to-custom-checkbox   Please add detail of property, re getting its path from context to use `bpy.ops.wm.context...` operators.

Comment: @batFINGER Thanks a lot for that reference! I was able to create this MCVE, but I must be missing something since it still does not work.

Comment: Can confirm that `bpy.ops.wm.context_toggle(data_path="scene.brush_properties.is_smooth_brush")` works as expected in the console. This will also work, but another shortcut assigned to 1   eg object mode hide collection. is taking precedence.  Search for those assigned to 1 and take them out to find the one, or choose another keymap.

Comment: @batFINGER thank you for your assistance, I think I can make this work now.