# Quickest way to create panel buttons with quick functionality

Tags: python

I need to create buttons in a custom panel to run some simple commands in python. For example toggling subsurf on and off with this script:

```
if bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["Subsurf"].show_viewport:
        bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["Subsurf"].show_viewport = False
    else:
        bpy.data.objects["Cube"].modifiers["Subsurf"].show_viewport = True
```

I need to create a bunch of similar buttons to toggle different things about the mesh. For example toggle display wire on the object, shade smooth/flat etc.

Is there a more practical way to do this than creating a dozens of separate operators for each of these commands. And using layout operator?

```
layout.operator("my.toggle_subsurf", text="Toggle Subsurf", icon="MOD_SUBSURF")
```

Comment: Related: [How to toggle visibilty of Subsurf modifier using shortcut?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/46848/31447)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Main concept is that *Operators* executing something based on given data *(e.g. convert all polygons of object xy to triangles)*. *Properties* on the other hand can either store the actual 'state' of something *(e.g. Wireframe `ON/OFF`)* or any 'value' *(e.g. Subdivisions=`3` or Crease=`0.0001`)*.

In fact, *Operators* like `OPS.object.delete()` can be *called* because these are 'functions' (note the *parentheses* at the end). However, a *Property* like `Object.wireframe` just stores `True` or `False` so it can not be *called* (it's basically not a 'function').

Means that you have to write an *Operator* if you want to change/toggle any *Property*.

---

Another way which you might not think of, is *expanding* each property to make it look like a 'Button', which also gives instant feedback to the user whether the property is *ON/OFF*.

[image]

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import (Panel, Operator)

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Operators
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class SimpleOperator(Operator):
    """Print object name in Console"""
    bl_idname = "object.simple_operator"
    bl_label = "Simple Object Operator"

    def execute(self, context):
        print (context.object)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Panel in Object Mode
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

class OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel(Panel):
    bl_idname = "object.custom_panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"   
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "Tools"
    bl_context = "objectmode"   


    @classmethod
    def poll(self,context):
        return context.object is not None

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        obj = context.object

        layout.label(text="Properties:")

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        row = col.row(align=True)
        row.prop(obj, "show_name", toggle=True, icon="FILE_FONT")
        row.prop(obj, "show_wire", toggle=True, text="Wireframe", icon="SHADING_WIRE")
        col.prop(obj, "show_all_edges", toggle=True, text="Show all Edges", icon="MOD_EDGESPLIT")
        layout.separator()

        layout.label(text="Operators:")

        col = layout.column(align=True)
        col.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="Execute Something", icon="CONSOLE")
        col.operator(SimpleOperator.bl_idname, text="Execute Something Else", icon="CONSOLE")

        layout.separator()

# ------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Registration
# ------------------------------------------------------------------------

def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SimpleOperator)

def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(OBJECT_PT_CustomPanel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SimpleOperator)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```

You should *definitely read*: [How to create a custom UI?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/57332/31447)